# What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, x86-16

For me, it just seems like a funky MOV. What's its purpose and when should I use it?

Comment: See also [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](//stackoverflow.com/a/46597375): LEA is just a shift-and-add instruction. It was probably added to 8086 because the hardware is already there to decode and calculate addressing modes, not because it's "intended" only for use with addresses. Remember that pointers are just integers in assembly.

Answer (score 1024):

As others have pointed out, LEA (load effective address) is often used as a "trick" to do certain computations, but that's not its primary purpose. The x86 instruction set was designed to support high-level languages like Pascal and C, where arrays—especially arrays of ints or small structs—are common. Consider, for example, a struct representing (x, y) coordinates:

```
struct Point
{
     int xcoord;
     int ycoord;
};
```

Now imagine a statement like:

```
int y = points[i].ycoord;
```

where `points[]` is an array of `Point`. Assuming the base of the array is already in `EBX`, and variable `i` is in `EAX`, and `xcoord` and `ycoord` are each 32 bits (so `ycoord` is at offset 4 bytes in the struct), this statement can be compiled to:

```
MOV EDX, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]    ; right side is "effective address"
```

which will land `y` in `EDX`. The scale factor of 8 is because each `Point` is 8 bytes in size. Now consider the same expression used with the "address of" operator &:

```
int *p = &points[i].ycoord;
```

In this case, you don't want the value of `ycoord`, but its address. That's where `LEA` (load effective address) comes in. Instead of a `MOV`, the compiler can generate

```
LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4]
```

which will load the address in `ESI`.

Comment: Wouldn't it have been cleaner to extend the `mov` instruction and leave off the brackets? `MOV EDX, EBX + 8*EAX + 4`

Comment: @imacake By replacing LEA with a specialized MOV you keep the syntax clean: [] brackets are always the equivalent of dereferencing a pointer in C. Without brackets, you always deal with the pointer itself.

Comment: @Natan Hey ASM is never trivial anyway! :D

Comment: Doing math in a MOV instruction (EBX+8*EAX+4) isn't valid.  LEA ESI, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4] is valid because this is an addressing mode that x86 supports. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes

Comment: So `LEA` is EXACTLY the same thing as `MOV` except it can copy the value into indexing registers (and can do the addressing calculation)?

Comment: @JonathanDickinson LEA is like a `MOV` with an indirect source, except it only does the indirection and not the `MOV`. It doesn't actually *read from* the computed address, just computes it.

Comment: Erik, tour comment is not accurate. MOV eax, [ebx+8*ecx+4] is valid. However MOV returns the contents of thst memory location whereas LEA returns the address

Comment: And there is even more general segment version of form `ds:(bx)` that specifies the segment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736663/what-does-the-colon-mean-in-x86-assembly-gas-syntax-as-in-dsbx

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 but that doesn't affect result of `lea`.

Comment: I still don't understand why the brackets are required. `LEA` doesn't do anything with whatever is stored at EBX + 8*EAX + 4; it just "loads the address" of whatever is stored there.. which is like doing `ptr2 = &(*ptr1)`. Too convoluted for what's basically just another arithmetic operation.

Comment: @Martin The syntax used in LEA has to use the parentheses, because LEA is built on addressing mode syntax.  given `MOV dest, whatever`, we can replace `MOV` with `LEA` to make `LEA dest, whatever`, without changing the syntax of `whatever`.   This is important because `whatever` has a syntax which denotes some kind of addressing mode. We want the address which pops out of that addressing mode, rather than the addressed object.   **Not all addressing modes have brackets!** For instance, `MOV EAX, globalvar` goes to `LEA EAX, globalvar`.

Comment: In that case, I'd argue that `LEA` should have its own, separate syntax since the brackets don't add any real value.

Comment: @Martin The missing piece of the puzzle is that LEA applies to any addressing mode, including ones that don't have a syntax with brackets. It's orthogonal to that syntax and I believe it's that way at the instruction encoding level also: the "mod/rm" bits in LEA are like those in MOV and other instructions.  We could invent a syntax like this "MOV dest, &source` where the `&` converts it to a `LEA` (and is available only in `MOV`, not in `ADD` or whatever).   A half page of Unix scripting can provide this syntax as a preprocessor. :)

Comment: Shouldnt the syntax of mov is `mov src dest`?

Comment: @EmmaHe It depends on which assembler you're using. If the assembler uses the Intel syntax (for example MASM, NASM, FASM) the equivalent is `mov dest src`, but if the assembler follows the AT&T syntax (such as GAS) it would be `mov src dest`.

Comment: Changing the **assembly syntax** to `MOV EDX, EBX + 8*EAX + 4` (without the brackets) would not change a thing. This would just be a different spelling for exactly the same opcode and operands. A conventional disassembler would look at the instruction that was assembled from this syntax and print it as `LEA [EDX, EBX + 8*EAX + 4]`.   However, the syntax `MOV EDX, EBX + 8*EAX + 4` looks silly  because it's doing arithmetic but is being called "move". `LEA` is good the way it is: perform just the address calculation of a MOV and then yield that as the result.

Comment: from http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~evans/cs216/guides/x86.html: mov syntax
mov <reg>,<mem> or mov <reg>,<const>; so EBX + 8*EAX + 4 is not a const but a mem. if it's a memory, it must use bracket and `mov` will move the data out instead of the address.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to be `mov edx, [ebx + 8*eax]` and then `mov edx, [edx + 4]` ?

Comment: So sum up, MOV with brackets will get what's at the address written in the brackets (which can be arithmetic or not). Without the brackets (no arithmetic possible), it will write the address to the register. LEA only works with the brackets (so arithmetic possible) and will basically do what MOV does when the brackets are not provided. So both are useful. Aside from going on the given address, MOV can also do what LEA does, except it can only do it without the brackets - but without them, no arithmetic is possible. So LEA "corrects" that. I think that's what I get of all this (hopefully right)

Comment: LEA is basically MOV without brackets , details may apply, but , to simplify, when you LEA EDX, [EBX + 8*EAX + 4] , it's the samething as MOV EDX, EBX + 8*EAX + 4 in your mind, but not in reality, because mov can't be used this way

Comment: Re: why was the ISA (and/or asm syntax) designed to use `lea eax, [ecx+4]` instead of providing a form of MOV that could do `mov eax, ecx+4`?  See [Why LEA(load effective address) is necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77416613)  .  (@Kaz makes several good points in this comment thread, including about MASM-style syntax where `mov eax, foo` is a load even without brackets.  Of course, you never actually want `lea eax, foo` except in 64-bit mode; `mov eax, OFFSET foo` is shorter machine code.  Other syntaxes like NASM require brackets around mem; NASM `mov edi,foo` is mov-immediate.)

Answer (score 653):

From the *"Zen of Assembly"* by Abrash:

> `LEA`, the only instruction that performs memory addressing calculations but doesn't actually address memory. `LEA` accepts a standard memory addressing operand, but does nothing more than store the calculated memory offset in the specified register, which may be any general purpose register.
>
> What does that give us? Two things that `ADD` doesn't provide:
>
> 1. the ability to perform addition with either two or three operands, and
> 2. the ability to store the result in *any* register; not just one of the source operands.

And `LEA` does not alter the flags.

Examples

- `LEA EAX, [ EAX + EBX + 1234567 ]` calculates `EAX + EBX + 1234567` (that's three operands)
- `LEA EAX, [ EBX + ECX ]` calculates `EBX + ECX` without overriding either with the result.
- multiplication by constant (by two, three, five or nine), if you use it like `LEA EAX, [ EBX + N * EBX ]` (N can be 1,2,4,8).

Other usecase is handy in loops: the difference between `LEA EAX, [ EAX + 1 ]` and `INC EAX` is that the latter changes `EFLAGS` but the former does not; this preserves `CMP` state.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK some examples: `LEA EAX, [ EAX + EBX + 1234567 ]` calculates the sum of `EAX`, `EBX` and `1234567` (that's three operands). `LEA EAX, [ EBX + ECX ]` calculates `EBX + ECX` _without_ overriding either with the result. The third thing `LEA` is used for (not listed by Frank) is _multiplication by constant_ (by two, three, five or nine), if you use it like `LEA EAX, [ EBX + N * EBX ]` (`N` can be 1,2,4,8). Other usecase is handy in loops: the difference between `LEA EAX, [ EAX + 1 ]` and `INC EAX` is that the latter changes `EFLAGS` but the former does not; this preserves `CMP` state

Comment: @FrankH. I still don't understand, so it loads a pointer onto somewhere else?

Comment: @ripDaddy69 yes, sort of - if by "load" you mean "performs the address calculation / pointer arithmetics". It does _not access memory_ (i.e. not "dereference" the pointer as it'd be called in C programming terms).

Comment: +1: This makes explicit what kinds of 'tricks' `LEA` can be used for... (see "LEA (load effective address) is often used as a "trick" to do certain computations" in IJ Kennedy's popular answer above)

Comment: There's a big difference between 2 operand LEA which is fast and 3 operand LEA which is slow. The Intel Optimization manual says fast path LEA is single cycle and slow path LEA takes three cycles. Moreover, on Skylake there are two fast path functional units (ports 1 and 5) and there's only one slow path functional unit (port 1). Assembly/Compiler Coding Rule 33 in the manual even warns against using 3 operand LEA.

Comment: @Olsonist Interesting note.

Comment: I felt a lack of exact numbers for this example, so here they are. Let's say EBX=5, ECX=3. Then after `LEA EAX, [EBX + ECX]` EAX will contain 8. And after `LEA EAX, [EBX + ECX + 2]` EAX will contain 10.

Comment: " (N can be 1,2,4,8)."
As documented in Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures
Software Developer’s Manual Volume 1
3.7.5 Specifying an Offset

Answer (score 132):

Another important feature of the `LEA` instruction is that it does not alter the condition codes such as `CF` and `ZF`, while computing the address by arithmetic instructions like `ADD` or `MUL` does. This feature decreases the level of dependency among instructions and thus makes room for further optimization by the compiler or hardware scheduler.

Comment: Yes, `lea` is sometimes useful for the compiler (or human coder) to do math without clobbering a flag result.  But `lea` isn't faster than `add`.  Most x86 instructions write flags.  High-performance x86 implementations have to rename EFLAGS or otherwise avoid [the write-after-write hazard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#Data_hazards) for normal code to run fast, so instructions that avoid flag writes aren't better because of that.  (*partial* flag stuff can create issues, see [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](//stackoverflow.com/q/36510095))

Comment: @PeterCordes : Hate to bring this up here but - am I alone in thinking this new [x86-lea] tag is redundant and unnecessary?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: Yeah, I think it's too specific.  It seems to confuse beginner who don't understand machine language and that everything (including pointers) are just bits / bytes / integers, so there are lots of questions about it with huge numbers of votes.  But having a tag for it implies that there's room for an open-ended number of future questions, when in fact there are about 2 or 3 total that aren't just duplicates.  (what is it?  How to use it for multiplying integers?   and how it runs internally on AGUs vs. ALUs and with what latency / throughput.  And maybe it's "intended" purpose)

Comment: @PeterCordes : I agree, and if anything all these posts being edited are pretty much a duplicate of a few of the exiting LEA related questions. Rather than a tag, any duplicates should be identified and marked imho.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: hang on tagging all the LEA questions, if you haven't already finished.  As discussed above, we think [tag:x86-lea] too specific for a tag, and there's not a lot of scope for future non-duplicate questions.  I think it would be a lot of work to *actually* choose a "best" Q&A as a dup target for most of them, though, or to actually decide which ones to get mods to merge.

Answer (score 113):

Despite all the explanations, LEA is an arithmetic operation:

```
LEA Rt, [Rs1+a*Rs2+b] =>  Rt = Rs1 + a*Rs2 + b
```

It's just that its name is extremelly stupid for a shift+add operation. The reason for that was already explained in the top rated answers (i.e. it was designed to directly map high level memory references).

Comment: And that the arithmetic is performed by the address-calculation hardware.

Comment: @BenVoigt I used to say that, because I'm an old bloke :-) Traditionally, x86 CPUs did use the addressing units for this, agreed. But the "separation" has become very blurry these days. Some CPUs no longer have _dedicated_ AGUs at all, others have chosen not to execute `LEA` on the AGUs but on the ordinary integer ALUs. One has to read the CPU specs very closely these days to find out "where stuff runs" ...

Comment: @FrankH.: out-of-order CPUs typically run LEA on ALUs, while some in-order CPUs (like Atom) sometimes run it on an AGUs (because they can't be busy handling a memory access).

Comment: No, the name is not stupid.  `LEA` gives you the address which arises from any memory-related addressing mode.   It is not a shift and add operation.

Comment: FWIW there are very few (if any) current x86 CPUs that perform the operation on the AGU. Most or all just use an ALU like any other arithmetic op.

Comment: it's very simple to understand the problem if you consider that an instruction set architecture is created to isolate the architecture details from the upper layers. Embedding the fact that LEA is executed in an AGU is clearly irrelevant and to the ISA and produces a wrong interpretation of the architecture and doubts about the instruction itself.

Comment: @Kaz: The only time `lea` isn't a shift-and-add instruction is x86-64 RIP-relative addressing modes.  You can also use it as a move (immediate or register), but that's just a degenerate case of shifting by zero or adding nothing.  I agree that the name is sensible, but it really is just a shift-and-add instruction that takes advantage of the memory-operand machine-code encoding.  (Or it was when it was named, before x86-64 existed.)  All x86 addressing modes (except RIP relative) are subsets of `[base + index*scale + displacement]`: i.e. shift and add.

Comment: @PeterCordes I suspect that in 386, at least, and its predecessors, it used the same logic as address mode calculation, subsequently retaining the address as the output, rather than doing a memory cycle to load or store through the calculated address. Most of those calculations are shift-and-add business, sure.

Comment: @Kaz: Yeah, it's a useful instruction and was cheap to implement in early CPUs by exposing the address-generation hardware. Some even still work that way, like K8/K10 for complex-LEA.  (As [Andy Glew explains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791798/what-is-the-eu-in-x86-architecture-calculates-effective-address), some CPUs have ALUs that can only handle 2 inputs, so some LEAs have to run on an AGU). But *the reason it's useful is that it's a shift+add instruction, and that it doesn't destroy any of its input registers*.  The execution details only matter when tuning for specific uarches.

Comment: My main point is that you should think of it as a general-purpose shift+add instruction so you aren't confused by seeing it used for non-pointers, and so you can spot use-cases where it saves instructions.  It's fast in all CPUs, but with weird latency quirks in in-order Atom where it does run on the AGUs.  (Inputs need to be ready sooner than for ALU uops).  (And yes, [RossRidge says 8086 ran it on the AGU](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29203242/224132), although I seem to recall someone else saying that 8086 didn't have dedicated AGUs, and did address calcs in the ALU...  Anyway, same diff)

Comment: @PeterCordes It's not just that LEA is likely implemented with the same addressing logic, but more importantly, the programmer view **through the assembly language** is that the same operand **syntax** is used that is used for expressing addressing modes.

Comment: in x86-16 you don't even have a shift and have a very limited number of register choices

Answer (score 93):

Maybe just another thing about LEA instruction.
You can also use LEA for fast multiplying registers by 3, 5 or 9.

```
LEA EAX, [EAX * 2 + EAX]   ;EAX = EAX * 3
LEA EAX, [EAX * 4 + EAX]   ;EAX = EAX * 5
LEA EAX, [EAX * 8 + EAX]   ;EAX = EAX * 9
```

Comment: +1 for the trick. But I would like to ask a question (may be stupid), why not directly multiply with three like this `LEA EAX, [EAX*3]` ?

Comment: @Abid Rahman K: There is no such as instruction unde x86 CPU instruction set.

Comment: @AbidRahmanK despite the intel asm syntax makes it look like a multiplication, the lea instruction can encode only shift operations. The opcode has 2 bits to describe the shift, hence you can multiply only by 1,2,4 or 8.

Comment: can you also use it for multiplying registers by 2,4 or 8?

Comment: @Koray Tugay: Yes you can, like: `lea     eax, [eax * 8]`

Comment: @GJ. Why did you give examples for 3 5 and 9 in your answer?

Comment: @Koray Tugay: You can use shift left like `shl`instruction for multiplying registers by 2,4,8,16... it is faster and shorter. But for multiplying with numbers different of power of 2 we normaly use `mul` instruction which is more pretentious and slower.

Comment: maybe `lea` will be used when we need to preserve the flags, like in some cases that `lea` is used instead of `add

Comment: @GJ. although there's no such encoding, some assemblers accept this as a shortcut, e.g. fasm. So e.g. `lea eax,[eax*3]` would translate to equivalent of `lea eax,[eax+eax*2]`.

Comment: @KorayTugay: It's sometimes worth using `lea edx, [eax*8]` to copy+shift, even though with no base register, the addressing mode needs a disp32 (4 bytes of zeros in this case).  So that LEA takes 7 bytes to encode: opcode + ModR/M + SIB(indexed addressing mod) + disp32=0.  mov + shl is actually smaller, but is 2 uops.  With a base register, for `[eax + eax]`, `[eax + eax*2]`, or whatever, no displacement is needed.

Comment: @GJ.: normally you use `imul ecx, ebx, 12345`.  You only use `mul` if you want the high-half result of a full multiply.  It can be worth using 2 `lea` instructions to replace a multiply, but on modern CPUs not 3.  Intel CPUs have 1c latency LEA with 1 or 2 components, including base + scaled-index, so you can do `lea eax, [eax+eax*4]` / `lea eax, [edx + eax*2]` as [part of a `tot = tot*10 + digit` loop for `atoi`, for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309749/nasm-assembly-convert-input-to-integer/49548057#49548057).  That's 2 cycle latency vs. 4 for `imul eax,10` / `add eax,edx`

Answer (score 73):

`lea` is an abbreviation of "load effective address". It loads the address of the location reference by the source operand to the destination operand. For instance, you could use it to:

```
lea ebx, [ebx+eax*8]
```

to move `ebx` pointer `eax` items further (in a 64-bit/element array) with a single instruction. Basically, you benefit from complex addressing modes supported by x86 architecture to manipulate pointers efficiently.

Answer (score 34):

The biggest reason that you use `LEA` over a `MOV` is if you need to perform arithmetic on the registers that you are using to calculate the address.  Effectively, you can perform what amounts to pointer arithmetic on several of the registers in combination effectively for "free."

What's really confusing about it is that you typically write an `LEA` just like a `MOV` but you aren't actually dereferencing the memory.  In other words:

`MOV  EAX, [ESP+4]`

This will move the content of what `ESP+4` points to into `EAX`.

`LEA EAX, [EBX*8]`

This will move the effective address `EBX * 8` into EAX, not what is found in that location.  As you can see, also, it is possible to multiply by factors of two (scaling) while a `MOV` is limited to adding/subtracting.

Comment: Sorry everyone.  @big.heart fooled me by giving an answer to this three hours ago, getting it to show up as "new" in my Assembly question scouring.

Comment: Why does the syntax use brackets when it does not do memory addressing?

Comment: @q4w56 This is one of those things where the answer is, "That's just how you do it."  I believe it's one of the reasons that people have such a hard time figuring out what `LEA` does.

Comment: @q4w56: it's a shift+add instruction that uses memory operand syntax *and* machine-code encoding.  On some CPUs it may even use the AGU hardware, but that's a historical detail.  The still-relevant fact is that the decoder hardware already exists for decoding this kind of shift+add, and LEA lets us use it for arithmetic instead of memory addressing.  (Or for address calculations if one input actually is a pointer).

Answer (score 28):

The 8086 has a large family of instructions that accept a register operand and an effective address, perform some computations to compute the offset part of that effective address, and perform some operation involving the register and the memory referred to by the computed address.  It was fairly simple to have one of the instructions in that family behave as above except for skipping that actual memory operation.  Thus, the instructions:

```
mov ax,[bx+si+5]
lea ax,[bx+si+5]
```

were implemented almost identically internally.  The difference is a skipped step.  Both instructions work something like:

```
temp = fetched immediate operand (5)
temp += bx
temp += si
address_out = temp  (skipped for LEA)
trigger 16-bit read  (skipped for LEA)
temp = data_in  (skipped for LEA)
ax = temp
```

As for why Intel thought this instruction was worth including, I'm not exactly sure, but the fact that it was cheap to implement would have been a big factor.  Another factor would have been the fact that Intel's assembler allowed symbols to be defined relative to the `BP` register.  If `fnord` was defined as a `BP`-relative symbol (e.g. `BP+8`), one could say:

```
mov ax,fnord  ; Equivalent to "mov ax,[BP+8]"
```

If one wanted to use something like `stosw` to store data to a BP-relative address, being able to say

```
mov ax,0 ; Data to store
mov cx,16 ; Number of words
lea di,fnord
rep movs fnord  ; Address is ignored EXCEPT to note that it's an SS-relative word ptr
```

was more convenient than:

```
mov ax,0 ; Data to store
mov cx,16 ; Number of words
mov di,bp
add di,offset fnord (i.e. 8)
rep movs fnord  ; Address is ignored EXCEPT to note that it's an SS-relative word ptr
```

Note that forgetting the world "offset" would cause the contents of location `[BP+8]`, rather than the value 8, to be added to `DI`.  Oops.

Answer (score 18):

The LEA (Load Effective Address) instruction is a way of obtaining the address which arises from any of the Intel processor's memory addressing modes.

That is to say, if we have a data move like this:

```
MOV EAX, <MEM-OPERAND>
```

it moves the contents of the designated memory location into the target register.

If we replace the `MOV` by `LEA`, then the address of the  memory location is calculated in exactly the same way by the `<MEM-OPERAND>` addressing expression. But instead of the contents of the memory location, we get the location itself into the destination.

`LEA` is not a specific arithmetic instruction; it is a way of intercepting the effective address arising from any one of the processor's memory addressing modes.

For instance, we can use `LEA` on just a simple direct address. No arithmetic is involved at all:

```
MOV EAX, GLOBALVAR   ; fetch the value of GLOBALVAR into EAX
LEA EAX, GLOBALVAR   ; fetch the address of GLOBALVAR into EAX.
```

This is valid; we can test it at the Linux prompt:

```
$ as
LEA 0, %eax
$ objdump -d a.out

a.out:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <.text>:
   0:   8d 04 25 00 00 00 00    lea    0x0,%eax
```

Here, there is no addition of a scaled value, and no offset.  Zero is moved into EAX.   We could do that using MOV with an immediate operand also.

This is the reason why people who think that the brackets in `LEA` are superfluous are severely mistaken; the brackets are not `LEA` syntax but are part of the addressing mode.

LEA is real at the hardware level. The generated instruction encodes the actual addressing mode and the processor carries it out to the point of calculating the address. Then it moves that address to the destination instead of generating a memory reference. (Since the address calculation of an addressing mode in any other instruction has no effect on CPU flags, `LEA` has no effect on CPU flags.)

Contrast with loading the value from address zero:

```
$ as
movl 0, %eax
$ objdump -d a.out | grep mov
   0:   8b 04 25 00 00 00 00    mov    0x0,%eax
```

It's a very similar encoding, see? Just the `8d` of `LEA` has changed to `8b`.

Of course, this `LEA` encoding is longer than moving an immediate zero into `EAX`:

```
$ as
movl $0, %eax
$ objdump -d a.out | grep mov
   0:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
```

There is no reason for `LEA` to exclude this possibility though just because there is a shorter alternative; it's just combining in an orthogonal way with the available addressing modes.

Answer (score 14):

As the existing answers mentioned, `LEA` has the advantages of performing memory addressing arithmetic without accessing memory, saving the arithmetic result to a different register instead of the simple form of add instruction. The real underlying performance benefit is that modern processor has a separate LEA ALU unit and port for effective address generation (including `LEA` and other memory reference address), this means the arithmetic operation in `LEA` and other normal arithmetic operation in ALU could be done in parallel in one core.

Check this article of Haswell architecture for some details about LEA unit:
http://www.realworldtech.com/haswell-cpu/4/

Another important point which is not mentioned in other answers is `LEA REG, [MemoryAddress]` instruction is PIC (position independent code) which encodes the PC relative address in this instruction to reference `MemoryAddress`. This is different from `MOV REG, MemoryAddress` which encodes relative virtual address and requires relocating/patching in modern operating systems (like ASLR is common feature). So `LEA` can be used to convert such non PIC to PIC.

Comment: The "separate LEA ALU" part is mostly untrue. Modern CPUs execute `lea` on one or more of the same ALUs that execute other arithmetic instructions (but generally fewer of them than other arithmetic). For instance, the Haswell CPU mentioned can execute `add` or `sub` or most other basic arithmetic operations on _four different_ ALUs, but can only execute `lea` on one (complex `lea`) or two (simple `lea`). More importantly, those two `lea`-capable ALUs are simply two of the four that can execute other instructions, so there is no parallelism benefit as claimed.

Comment: The article you linked (correctly) shows that LEA is on the same port as an integer ALU (add/sub/boolean), and the integer MUL unit in Haswell.  (And vector ALUs including FP ADD/MUL/FMA).  The simple-only LEA unit is on port 5, which also runs ADD/SUB/whatever, and vector shuffles, and other stuff.  The only reason I'm not downvoting is that you point out the use of RIP-relative LEA (for x86-64 only).

Answer (score 10):

It seems that lots of answers already complete, I'd like to add one more example code for showing how the lea and move instruction work differently when they have the same expression format.

To make a long story short, lea instruction and mov instructions both can be used with the parentheses enclosing the src operand of the instructions. When they are enclosed with the **()**, the expression in the **()** is calculated in the same way; however, two instructions will interpret the calculated value in the src operand in a different way.

Whether the expression is used with the lea or mov, the src value is calculated as below.

> **D ( Rb, Ri, S )** => **(Reg[Rb]+S*Reg[Ri]+ D)**

However, when it is used with the mov instruction, it tries to access the value pointed to by the address generated by the above expression and store it to the destination.

In contrast of it, when the lea instruction is executed with the above expression, it loads the generated value as it is to the destination.

The below code executes the lea instruction and mov instruction with the same parameter. However, to catch the difference, I added a user-level signal handler to catch the segmentation fault caused by accessing a wrong address as a result of mov instruction.

**Example code**

```c
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1 /* To pick up REG_RIP */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <signal.h>

uint32_t
register_handler(uint32_t event, void (*handler)(int, siginfo_t *, void *))
{
    uint32_t ret = 0;
    struct sigaction act;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof(act));
    act.sa_sigaction = handler;
    act.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
    ret = sigaction(event, &act, NULL);
    return ret;
}

void segfault_handler(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *priv)
{
    ucontext_t *context = (ucontext_t *)(priv);
    uint64_t rip = (uint64_t)(context->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
    uint64_t faulty_addr = (uint64_t)(info->si_addr);

    printf("inst at 0x%lx tries to access memory at %ld, but failed\n",
           rip, faulty_addr);
    exit(1);
}

int main(void)
{
    int result_of_lea = 0;

    register_handler(SIGSEGV, segfault_handler);

    // initialize registers %eax = 1, %ebx = 2

    // the compiler will emit something like
    // mov $1, %eax
    // mov $2, %ebx
    // because of the input operands
    asm("lea 4(%%rbx, %%rax, 8), %%edx \t\n"
        : "=d"(result_of_lea) // output in EDX
        : "a"(1), "b"(2)      // inputs in EAX and EBX
        :                     // no clobbers
    );

    // lea 4(rbx, rax, 8),%edx == lea (rbx + 8*rax + 4),%edx == lea(14),%edx
    printf("Result of lea instruction: %d\n", result_of_lea);

    asm volatile("mov 4(%%rbx, %%rax, 8), %%edx"
                 :
                 : "a"(1), "b"(2)
                 : "edx" // if it didn't segfault, it would write EDX
    );
}
```

**Execution result**

```
Result of lea instruction: 14
inst at 0x4007b5 tries to access memory at 14, but failed
```

Comment: Breaking up your inline asm into separate statements is unsafe, and your clobbers lists are incomplete.  The basic-asm block tells the compiler is has no clobbers, but it actually modifies several registers.  Also, you can use `=d` to tell the compiler the result is in EDX, saving a `mov`.  You also left out an early-clobber declaration on the output.  This does demonstrate what you're trying to demonstrate, but is also a misleading bad example of inline asm that will break if used in other contexts.  That's a Bad Thing for a stack overflow answer.

Comment: If you don't want to write `%%` on all those register names in Extended asm, then use input constraints.  like `asm("lea 4(%%ebx, %%eax, 8), %%edx" : "=d"(result_of_lea) : "a"(1), "b"(2));`.  Letting the compiler init registers means you don't have to declare clobbers, either.  You're overcomplicating things by xor-zeroing before mov-immediate overwrites the whole register, too.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks, Peter, do you want me to delete this answer or modify it following your comments?

Comment: If you did want to leave in the mov instructions instead of telling people to single-step in GDB to see the compiler generated insns, `asm("mov ... %%eax\n" "mov ... %%ebx\n" "lea 4(%%ebx, %%eax, 8), %%edx" : "=d"(result_of_lea) :: "eax", "ebx");`.  It doesn't need to be `volatile` because we print the result; it won't be optimized away.  (The `mov` does, because you didn't write any code to use the `mov` result.)

Comment: If you fix the inline asm, it's not doing any harm and maybe makes a good concrete example for beginners that didn't understand the other answers.  No need to delete, and it's an easy fix like I showed in my last comment.  I think it would be worth an upvote if the bad example of inline asm was fixed into a "good" example.  (I didn't downvote)

Comment: @PeterCordes I tried to modify the code following your comments; could you please go through it once again to check if it is still wrong? I appreciate your help.

Comment: Yup, that looks right.  You might add a clobber or dummy output for the `mov`, though.  Fixed that for you and added comments to the asm statements.

Comment: Thanks :D I also learned that input operand can be used to let the compiler initialize some registers.

Comment: BTW, it's strange to use 32-bit addressing modes in x86-64 code.  Your signal handler use `REG_RIP` and other 64-bit-specific stuff, so it would have been more normal to use `lea 4(%%rbx, %%rax, 8), %%edx`, so the machine code doesn't need an address-size override prefix or a REX prefix.

Comment: Oh yes, you are right, I should have matched two code. However, I used 32bit assembly intentionally because some other answers use the same code for wrongly saying that mov cannot be used with 4(ebx, eax, 8) format; but I agree the unmatched code may confuse others. If I want to modify the code as you recommended, should I initialize the rax & rbx not the eax & ebx?

Comment: Where does anyone say that `mov 4(%ebx, %eax, 8), %edx` is invalid?  Anyway, yes, for `mov` it would make sense to write `"a"(1ULL)` to tell the compiler you have a 64-bit value, and thus it needs to make sure it's extended to fill the whole register.  In practice it will still use `mov $1, %eax`, because writing EAX zero-extends into RAX, unless you have a weird situation of surrounding code where the compiler knew that RAX = `0xff00000001` or something.  For `lea`, you're still using 32-bit operand-size, so the any stray high bits in input registers have no effect on the 32-bit result.

Comment: See [Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711) for LEA register choices, and [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137) for writing to 32-bit registers.

Comment: Turns out `"a"(1)` does always result in the full RAX = 1, not just the low 32 bits (EAX).  This appears to be an implementation detail, though, because the effect I was talking about (not zero or sign-extending to the full register for `int` inputs) does happen for variables that aren't known at compile time.  https://godbolt.org/z/vocejs shows gcc and clang both `mov` repeatedly for constants but not runtime variables.  But gcc reuse the EAX=1 if you repeat the same input.  (clang doesn't!)

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for useful references and the code. I am still bit confused about the part that you've mentioned about the variables that aren't known at compile time. Does it mean that the second asm statement in the function foo is translated into mov rax? And for the above code in my answer, it seems that using 64bit input operands and 32bit output operand is the most efficient format of the lea instruction in the aspect of the binary size (1byte lesser than having 64bit output). Is it correct? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, the default address size in 64-bit mode is 64-bit, and the default operand-size is 32-bit.  Like I explained in detail in the footnotes in [Which 2's complement integer operations can be used without zeroing high bits in the inputs, if only the low part of the result is wanted?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34377711), those sizes avoid both REX and address-size prefixes.  As for `mov rax`, no, neither statement writes `rax`.  If you meant `mov rdx, [mem]`, no, that would be a 64-bit load.  You could think of `mov` to a 32-bit register as being implicitly a `movzx qword, dword`, but that's

Answer (score 9):

The LEA instruction can be used to avoid time consuming calculations of effective addresses by the CPU. If an address is used repeatedly it is more effective to store it in a register instead of calculating the effective address every time it is used.

Comment: Not necessarily on modern x86. Most of the addressing modes have the same cost, with some caveats. So `[esi]` is rarely cheaper than say `[esi + 4200]` and is only rarely cheaper than `[esi + ecx*8 + 4200]`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope `[esi]` isn't cheaper than `[esi + ecx*8 + 4200]`. But why bother comparing? They are not equivalent. If you want the former to designate the same memory location as the latter, you need additional instructions: you have to add to `esi` the value of `ecx` multiplied by 8. Uh oh, multiplication is going to clobber your CPU flags! Then you have to add the 4200. These additional instructions add to the code size (taking up space in the instruction cache, cycles to fetch).

Comment: @Kaz - I think you were missing my point (or else I missed the point of the OP). My understanding is that the OP is saying that if you are going to use something like `[esi + 4200]` repeatedly in a sequence of instructions, then it is better to first load the effective address into a register and use that. For example, rather than writing `add eax, [esi + 4200]; add ebx, [esi + 4200]; add ecx, [esi + 4200]`, you should prefer `lea edi, [esi + 4200]; add eax, [edi]; add ebx, [edi]; add ecx, [edi]`, which is rarely faster. At least that's the plain interpretation of this answer.

Comment: So the reason I was comparing `[esi]` and `[esi + 4200]` (or `[esi + ecx*8 + 4200]` is that this is the simplification the OP is proposing (as I understand it): that N instructions with the same complex address are transformed into N instructions with simple (one reg) addressing, plus one `lea`, since complex addressing is "time consuming". In fact, it is slower even on modern x86, but only latency-wise which seems unlikely to matter for consecutive instructions with the same address.

Comment: @BeeOnRope I see; we do this LEA up front to simplify the subsequent addresses (eliminate repetition of the same effective address). That doesn't, by itself, buy anything. Still, one thing we did achieve was that `ecx` is no longer required as an operand once we have the address in `esi`. If the register can be put to use, that could help in some way.

Comment: Perhaps you relieve some register pressure, yes - but the opposite may be the case: if the registers you generated the effective address with are live, you need _another_ register to save the result of `lea` so it increases pressure in that case. In general, storing intermediates is a cause of register pressure, not a solution to it - but I think in most situations it is a wash. @Kaz

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example.

```
// compute parity of permutation from lexicographic index
int parity (int p)
{
  assert (p >= 0);
  int r = p, k = 1, d = 2;
  while (p >= k) {
    p /= d;
    d += (k << 2) + 6; // only one lea instruction
    k += 2;
    r ^= p;
  }
  return r & 1;
}
```

With -O (optimize) as compiler option, gcc will find the lea instruction for the indicated code line.

Answer (score 7):

## LEA vs MOV (reply to the original question)

`LEA` is not a funky `MOV`. When you use `MOV`, it calculates the address and accesses the memory. `LEA` just calculates the address, it doesn't actually access memory. This is the difference.

In 8086 and later, `LEA` just sets a sum of up to two source registers and an immediate value to a destination register. For example, `lea bp, [bx+si+3]` sets to the bp register the sum of `bx` plus `si` plus 3. You cannot achieve this calculation to save the result to a register with `MOV`.

The 80386 processor introduced a series of scaling modes, in which the index register value can be multiplied by a valid scaling factor to obtain the displacement. The valid scale factors are 1, 2, 4, and 8. Therefore, you can use instructions like `lea ebp, [ebx+esi*8+3]`.

## LDS & LES (optional further reading)

In contrast to `LEA`, there are instructions `LDS` and `LES`, that, to the contrary, load values from memory to the pair of registers: one segment register (`DS` or `ES`) and one general register. There are also versions for the other registers: `LFS`, `LGS` and `LSS` for `FS`, `GS` and `SS` segment registers, respectively (introduced in 80386).

So, these instructions load "far" pointer - a pointer consisting of a 16-bit segment selector and a 16-bit (or a 32-bit, depending on the mode) offset, so the total far pointer size was 32-bit in 16-bit mode and 48-bit in 32-bit mode.

These are handy instructions for 16-bit mode, be it 16-bit real mode or 16-bit protected mode.

Under 32-bit mode, there is no need in these instructions since OSes set all segment bases to zero (flat memory model), so there is no need to load segment registers.  We just use 32-bit pointers, not 48.

Under 64-bit modes, these instructions are not implemented. Their opcodes give access violation interrupt (exception). Since Intel's implementation of VEX - "vector extensions - (AVX), Intel took their opcodes of `LDS` and `LES` and started using them for VEX prefixes. As Peter Cordes pointed out, that is why only x/ymm0..7 are accessible in 32-bit mode (quote): "the VEX prefixes were carefully designed to only overlap with invalid encodings of LDS and LES in 32-bit mode, where R̅ X̅ B̅ are all 1. That's why some of the bits are inverted in VEX prefixes".

Comment: `[bx*2+si+3]` isn't a valid 16-bit addressing mode.  16-bit doesn't allow any scale factors.   `lea bp, [ebx*2 + esi + 3]` would be legal, though, in 16-bit mode on a 386 or later.  (Normally you write the base first and then the scaled-index, but assemblers would accept that.)

Comment: *As a result, 256-bit AVX (YMM) registers are only available in 64-bit mode.* - Nope, but that is why only `x/ymm0..7` are accessible in 32-bit mode.  The VEX prefixes were carefully designed to only overlap with *invalid* encodings of LDS and LES in 32-bit mode, where R̅ X̅ B̅ are all 1.  That's why some of the bits are inverted in VEX prefixes.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VEX_prefix)

Comment: LES/LDS/... being useless in 32-bit mode is only by convention; OSes choose to use a flat memory model.  The hardware does support non-zero segment bases in 32-bit mode, unlike 64-bit mode.  So it's true in practice for normal OSes, but not necessarily for x86 in general.  So maybe "since OSes set all segment registers the same" or something, to imply that it's a choice, not a requirement, for 32-bit mode to work that way, but still without spending a lot of words on it and distracting from your point.

Comment: @PeterCordes I have added headers to delimit the reply to the original question and the optional further reading. Do you agree with the reply to the original section? Should I edit the "further reading" section to address your observation?

Comment: @PeterCordes, thank you for the observation that the scaling factor only appeared in 80386, I forgot that. I have reviewed my 27-years old assembly programs like https://github.com/maximmasiutin/exegrab/blob/master/exegrab.asm and there were indeed no scaling factor used.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's a good idea to still edit more clearly why LES/LDS aren't used.  I made an edit, and also fixed your mention of SSE2 for VEX prefixes.

Comment: @PeterCordes - thank you for your edits. Do I need to edit something more?

Comment: Not that I noticed, otherwise I would have fixed it or mentioned it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I think it's somewhat sad that Intel made the segment registers on the 80386 only 16 bits.  A useful trick for some kinds of DOS programs was to segment-align data items, which allowed their address to be stored using only two bytes rather than four.  If one were keeping a doubly linked list, and had outside references as well, the memory lost by padding the size would be balanced out by the fact that pointers would be smaller and faster to work with.  Frameworks like Java and .NET could have benefited hugely from the ability to use 32-bit references to identify storage...

Comment: ...within a much larger address space, especially if segment registers could use some bits to select a segment descriptor and some to apply a scaled offset, in configurable fashion.  The biggest problems with segmentation on the 8086 and 80286 architectures was the fact that there was only one mostly-uncommitted segment register (ES) and the lack of proper language support.  Other than that, I think segmentation was an under-appreciated feature.

Comment: @supercat: Protected-mode segment registers are indices into a GDT or LDT.  You're maybe picturing a segment reg where a couple bits are a selector index for a table of permission / privilege-level / limit, and the rest are used (shifted) as a base address, like in real mode?  Or some other design that would allow efficient (in space and cycles) updates of an Sreg similar to real mode.  Out-of-order exec CPUs would then need to rename segment registers and track which loads/stores were using which.  Some [uarches did do that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51163779/224132) so it's not impossible.

Comment: @PeterCordes: That would be the basic concept.  There are many approaches that could have been used, with different trade-offs between complexity and address range, such as having behavior that's almost exactly like real mode except that the top 4 bits would select the scale factor for the bottom 28, which would be simple and cheap but allow a mixture of different sizes of objects to be allocated in regions of memory with different "alignment" requirements.

Comment: @supercat: you're not leaving any bits for privilege-level, and (for CS) operating mode (default of 16 vs. 32-bit operand-size and address-size).  Or for a segment *limit*.  I guess you're picturing 386 should have used a totally separate mechanism to do privilege-level and mode switching (or that CS would still work like it does now).  But have other segments use segmentation mostly real-mode style just to expand the virtual address space beyond 4GiB?  But then the page-tables would have more virtual bits to translate, so two levels of 10 bits each wouldn't do it. 4GB was already huge for 386

Comment: @PeterCordes: There could be advantages to including such things within a segment register, but doing so would also add considerable complexity if one wanted to process segment-register loads quickly.  Treating segment-register prefixes largely as an extended addressing mode which formed a physical address from a pair of 32-bit numbers would make it easy to expand beyond 4GiB the address space that could be operated upon with 32-bit object references.  If a system used a fixed 4-bit shift like real mode, expansion to 64GiB would be trivial, but if upper bits could select a scale factor...

Comment: ...it would be practical to go well beyond that.  I don't know what ranges of scale factors would be most useful, but even if the choices were only x16, x256, and x4096, while 28 bits were available for scaled addresses, that would allow 4GiB of objects whose size was rounded to the next multiple of 16, *plus* 64GiB of objects whose size was rounded to the next multiple of 256, *plus* 1TiB of objects whose size was rounded to the next multiple of 4096, all while leaving 13/16 of the segment address space open for future expansion.

Comment: @PeterCordes: Perhaps one could say that if the top two bits weren't 00, they would be interpreted as addresses associated with segment descriptor 0, using 16/256/4096 scaling for the other 30 bits (expanding by a factor of four the address spaces described above) but if top bits were 00, some bits would be interpreted as a segment selector.  As it is, some Java implementations handle object references in a manner similar to real mode, but are limited to a scale factor of 8 because that's as high as the `base+scale*index+displacement` addressing mode can go.

Comment: @supercat: yeah, that design space has some interesting choices if 386 were being designed now, or in the mid 90s.  At the time, it seems like a sensible choice to assume that a flat up-to-4GiB address space would be fine for 32-bit pointers. 286 had already repurposed segment registers as GDT selectors, so yet another different interpretation would have been a bit much.

Comment: @PeterCordes: It's too bad I don't think the designers of the 80286 recognized what was uniquely good and bad about the 8086 design.  The 8086 architecture could have been extended to smoothly support 16MiB or more of storage smoothly, with minimal time or memory space overhead, by allowing different regions of the "segment space" to have separately-programmable scale factors.  The 80286 threw out the ability to treat memory as a contiguous sequence of 16-byte paragraphs, but failed to fix the biggest problem with the 8086: the fact that it only had one "non-committed" segment register.

Answer (score 5):

LEA : just an "arithmetic" instruction..

MOV transfers data between operands but lea is just calculating

Comment: LEA obviously moves data; it has a destination operand. LEA doesn't always calculate; it calculates if the effective address expressed in the source operand calculates. LEA EAX, GLOBALVAR doesn't calculate; it just moves the address of GLOBALVAR into EAX.

Comment: @Kaz thanks for your feedback. my source was "LEA (load effective address) is essentially an arithmetic instruction—it doesn’t
perform any actual memory access, but is commonly used for calculating
addresses (though you can calculate general purpose integers with it)." form [Eldad-Eilam book](https://www.amazon.com/Reversing-Secrets-Engineering-Eldad-Eilam/dp/0764574817) page 149

Comment: @Kaz: That's why LEA is redundant when the address is already a link-time constant; use `mov eax, offset GLOBALVAR` instead.  You *can* use LEA, but it's slightly larger code-size than `mov r32, imm32` and runs on fewer ports, *because it still goes through the address-calculation process*.  `lea reg, symbol` is only useful in 64-bit for a RIP-relative LEA, when you need PIC and/or addresses outside the low 32 bits.  In 32 or 16-bit code, there is zero advantage.  LEA is an arithmetic instruction that exposes the ability of the CPU to decode / compute addressing modes.

Comment: @Kaz: by the same argument, you could say that `imul eax, edx, 1` doesn't calculate: it just copies edx to eax.  But actually it runs your data through the multiplier with 3 cycle latency.  Or that `rorx eax, edx, 0` just copies (rotate by zero).

Comment: @PeterCordes My point is that both LEA EAX, GLOBALVAL and MOV EAX, GLOBALVAR just grab the address from an immediate operand. There is no multiplier of 1, or offset of 0 being applied; it could be that way at the hardware level but it's not seen in the assembly language or instruction set.

Comment: @Kaz: At the machine-code level, the addressing mode does have to encode that there's no base.  I admit that's not quite the same as an explicit `+0` or something.  But there's still a ModR/M byte for LEA, to specify the `disp32` immediate displacement, while `MOV r32,imm32` is just opcode + imm32, if you're thinking about the machine-code instruction set rather than the asm-source level syntax.  (And you're using MASM syntax, which omits the `[]` around symbols as memory operands.  So `mov eax, OFFSET globalvar` is taking something simpler than `globalvar`: just its offset.)

Answer (score 4):

All normal "calculating" instructions like adding multiplication, exclusive or set the status flags like zero, sign. If you use a complicated address, `AX xor:= mem[0x333 +BX + 8*CX]`  the flags are set according to the xor operation.

Now you may want to use the address multiple times. Loading such an addres into a register is never intended to set status flags and luckily it doesn't. The phrase "load effective address" makes the programmer aware of that. That is where the weird expression comes from.

It is clear that once the processor is capable of using the complicated address to process its content, it is capable of calculating it for other purposes. Indeed it can be used to perform a transformation `x <- 3*x+1` in one instruction. This is a general rule in assembly programming: **Use the instructions however it rocks your boat.**
The only thing that counts is whether the particular transformation embodied by the instruction is useful for you.

Bottom line

```
MOV, X| T| AX'| R| BX|
```

and

```
LEA, AX'| [BX]
```

have the same effect on *AX* but not on the status flags.
(This is *ciasdis* notation.)

Comment: "This is a general rule in assembly programming: Use the instructions however it rocks your boat." I wouldn't personally hand that advice out, on account of things like `call lbl` `lbl: pop rax` technically "working" as a way to get the value of `rip`, but you'll make branch prediction very unhappy. Use the instructions however you want, but don't be surprised if you do something tricky and it has consequences you didn't foresee

Comment: @The6P4C That is a useful caveat. However if there is no alternative to making the branch prediction unhappy, one has to go for it. There is another general rule in assembly programming. There may be alternative ways to do something and you must choose wisely from alternatives.There are hundreds of way to get the content of register BL into register AL.  If the remainder of RAX need not be preserved LEA may be an option. Not affecting the flags may be a good idea on some of the thousands of types of x86 processors. Groetjes Albert

Answer (score 3):

Forgive me if someone already mentioned, but in case anyone's wondering about the bad old days of x86 when memory segmentation was still relevant: you will always get the same results from these two instructions:

```
LEA AX, DS:[0x1234]
```

and

```
LEA AX, CS:[0x1234]
```

The "effective address" is just the offset part of the seg:off logical address.  In this case, 0x1234.

LEA does *not* add the segment base.  That would defeat one of the original use-cases, for doing address math to get a pointer (offset) you could actually dereference.  Such as `lea bx, [array + si]`.  If that added DS base to give a linear address, a later `mov ax, [bx]` would add the DS base *again*.
Also, the 20-bit result would often not fit in a 16-bit register.

See https://www.stevemorse.org/8086/index.html - the architect of 8086 wrote a book about the instruction set, and it's now free on his web site.  The section on LEA mentions some of his design intent.

Comment: The "effective address" is just the "offset" part of a `seg:off` pair.  LEA isn't affected by the segment base; both those instructions will (inefficiently) put `0x1234` into AX.  x86 unfortunately doesn't have an easy way to calculate a full linear address (effective + segment base) into a register or register-pair.

Comment: @PeterCordes Very useful, thanks for correcting me.

Comment: Since this previously-wrong and never got deleted (and had 2 upvotes despite that), I rewrote it to say the opposite thing about this example, and explain why.  Perhaps it even does illustrate one of the purposes of LEA, now.