# What do the brackets mean in NASM syntax for x86 asm?

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

Given the following code:

```
L1     db    "word", 0

       mov   al, [L1]
       mov   eax, L1
```

What do the brackets in `[L1]` represent?

---

This question is specifically about NASM.  The other major flavour of Intel-syntax assembly is MASM style, where brackets work differently when there's no register involved:
See [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32)

Comment: Note that brackets are weird and less simple in MASM : [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743) Usually they mean dereference, but sometimes they're ignored.  (And sometimes it dereferences even without brackets).

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`[L1]` means the memory contents at address L1. After running `mov al, [L1]` here, The `al` register will receive the byte at address L1 (the letter 'w').

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am starting to learn asm. If I understand this correctly, "mov al, [L1]" would move 'w' into al, and "mov eax, L1" would move the address of L1 into eax. Is that correct?

Comment: yes. and if you did `mov ebx,L1 -- mov al,[ebx]` then `al` would be 'w' in that case too.

Comment: The exception to this is LEA.

Comment: @interjay, So why is it that the brackets are not needed in the second line: `mov   eax, L1`?

Comment: @Pacerier It depends on the assembler you're using, but usually without the brackets it will get the memory address, not the contents.

Comment: @Pacerier: NASM/FASM assemble `mov eax, L1` to `mov eax, imm32` with the address.  MASM / GAS (.intel_syntax noprefix) assemble that to a load, exactly the same as `mov eax, [L1]`.  See [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743).  Some MASM users prefer to always use `[]` around memory references even when not required, but to `mov reg, imm` you need `mov eax, OFFSET L1` in MASM/GAS-Intel syntax.

Answer (score 56):

Operands of this type, such as `[ebp]`, are called [memory operands](https://github.com/simon987/Much-Assembly-Required/wiki/Basic-Assembly-tutorial#instruction-and-operands).

All the answers here are good, but I see that none tells about the caveat in following this as a rigid rule - *if brackets, then dereference*, **except when it's the `lea` instruction**.

`lea` is an exception to the above rule. Say we've

```asm
mov eax, [ebp - 4]
```

The value of `ebp` is subtracted by 4 and the brackets indicate that the resulting value is taken as an address and the value residing at that address is stored in `eax`. However, in `lea`'s case, the brackets wouldn't mean that:

```asm
lea eax, [ebp - 4]
```

The value of `ebp` is subtracted by 4 and the resulting value is stored in `eax`. This instruction would just calculate the address and store the calculated value in the destination register. See [What is the difference between MOV and LEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea/1699778#1699778) for further details.

Comment: The first link is dead. Here is a snapshot: https://web.archive.org/web/20180331051340/http://www.imada.sdu.dk/Courses/DM18/Litteratur/IntelnATT.htm

Comment: @Hritik Thanks for flagging the broken link!  Fixed with a better link :)

Answer (score 30):

Simply means to get the memory at the address marked by the label L1.

If you like C, then think of it like this: `[L1]` is the same as `*L1`

Comment: @user2485710 No, `*p` means dereference the char pointed by `p`. Strings have nothing to do with this.

Comment: `*L1` only works if you think in terms of asm labels as equivalent to C static/global arrays, like `static char L1[] = "word";` in this question.  Then in C, `L1` has type `char*` and is the address.  `*L1` has type `char` and is the first byte.  `mov eax, [L1]` in asm is like memcpy into a uint32_t, or deref of an unaligned / strict-aliasing-safe `uint32_t*`.

Answer (score 12):

The brackets mean to de-reference an address. For example

```
mov eax, [1234]
```

means, mov the contents of address 1234 to EAX. So:

```
1234 00001
```

EAX will contain 00001.

Answer (score 2):

[Direct memory addressing](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/X86_Architecture#Addressing_modes) - `al` will be loaded with the value located at memory address `L1`.

Answer (score 1):

As with many assembler languages, this means indirection. In other words, the first `mov` loads `al` with the *contents* of `L1` (the byte `'w'` in other words), not the address.

Your second `mov` actually loads `eax` with the *address* `L1` and you can later dereference that to get or set its content.

In both those cases, `L1` is conceptually considered to be the address.

Answer (score 1):

They mean that instead of moving the value of the register or numeric value `L1` into the register `al`, treat the register value or numeric value `L1` as a pointer into memory, fetch the contents of that memory address, and move that contents into `al`.

In this instance, L1 is a memory location, but the same logic would apply if a register name was in the brackets:

```
mov al, [ebx]
```

Also known as a load.

Answer (score 1):

In MASM, brackets work like NASM when used with registers, and in that case are not optional.  (Things are different for addressing modes that don't involve a register, see [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25129743/confusing-brackets-in-masm32))

The brackets indicate that the register contains a pointer, and that the machine code wants the value of that pointer (pointers are in byte-addressing: a pointer is the xth byte of memory; a byte is 8 binary digits; one hexadecimal digit is 4 binary digits; as a byte is 2 hexadecimal digits; starting from there); if it's in the src part of the instruction.

- However, if dst has the brackets: memory at that address is an operand for the instruction. (Memory as in pointer of "byte-addressing" talked about, previously.)

In binary machine code, (typing hexadecimal digits in notepad.exe then converting hexadecimal digits into \xhexadecimal result~python_reference) to get the value of a pointer in a register, it can be defined in the ModR/M byte of the instruction that's going to be written in notepad.exe which is 10 characters I believe. (I'm finishing my MASM experience first, then I'm going to move on to scavenge information about what to type into notepad.exe through readings of window's kernel/malware analysis; I'll come back to this post and write up an example)

```
1 .686
2 .model flat, c
3 option casemap :none
4 
5 include C:\masm32\include\kernel32.inc
6 includelib C:\masm32\lib\kernel32.lib
7 
8 .data 
9     message db "Hello world!", 0
10 .code
11 
12 main proc
13  call testfunc
14  COMMENT @ 
15  push 0FFFFh
16  push testfunc
17  pop ax
18  @
19  invoke ExitProcess, 404
20 main ENDP
21 
22 testfunc proc
23  sub esp, 1
24  mov al, 0FFh
25  mov [esp], al
26  COMMENT @
27  push 0FFFFh
28  push 05EFFB880h
29  push 0773BFF5Ch
30  push 0FB038Fh
31  mov al, [esp+8]
32  @
33  invoke ExitProcess, [esp]
34 testfunc ENDP
35 
36 END main
```

Windows:
If you would type the result of executing this, and compare:

> C:\masm32\bin\ml /c /Zd /coff script_name.asm
> C:\masm32\bin\Link /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE script_name.obj
> script_name.exe
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%

The program's exit status (printed with `echo`) would be a the number stored to stack memory with `mov [esp], al` as the arg to ExitProcess, ending in hex FF.  (`%ERRORLEVEL%` converts the number to a string of decimal digits, not hex, but it's the same number.)

However, without the **[]** around `[esp]`: we also have to change AL to EAX (because x86 CPUs don't have an instruction to move 8-bit registers to bottom of 32-bit registers).  And remove the brackets around the last time the letters 'esp' was used in the lines of code; it would result in the pointer to the stack region in esp.

```
1 testfunc proc
2   mov eax, esp
3   mov bl, 0FFh
4   mov [eax], bl
5   COMMENT @
6   push 0FFFFh
7   push 05EFFB880h
8   push 0773BFF5Ch
9   push 0FB038Fh
10  mov al, [esp+8]
11  @
12  invoke ExitProcess, [esp]
13 testfunc ENDP
```

Tag: optional brackets

The above code is proof that the brackets ALWAYS WORK (uses the value inside whatever the code is as a pointer and gets the value of the pointer) in language interpreting machine code into a readable way instead of bytes and knowing how the Windows kernel would execute an exe file (reverse engineer window's kernel to make your own exe files from scratch inside notepad, which there isn't enough support in; however, malware analysis does have enough support.)

(If you want to test the code: you replace the lines with the testfunc in last code, and execute it the same way with the lines): In this case, eax is equal to esp's pointer in memory of the stack segment (stack segment is important because it has its own instructions: PUSH and POP 32-bit values from / to an immediate, register, or memory operand). So when you execute it, the bare `esp` operand is the value of the ESP register, a pointer value, not memory contents on the stack.

---

I'll come back and edit this post once in a while (if I actually get really good at assembly.); So, this can be an ultimate guide to assembly. I just got started in assembly and making a quick length of the most significant bit finder in a specific range script in assembly.

Resources that have helped me gotten to make this script so far:
5 hour tutorial of the entirety of C++:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLnPwxZdW4Y&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org
  I recommend after this doing a scavenger hunt of learning HTML/CSS/JS and making a calculator website (a drag and drop of html file to Microsoft Edge), and scavenger hunt of coding a video game like Undertale (a drag and drop of html file to Microsoft Edge), and then learn Python3 just for jokes.

Helps me find out what stuff like DWORDs are (unsigned long).
https://www.bing.com

- Please read the intel software developer manual, it tells you stuff like how if you change a position in memory, it's called the command register of advanced programmable interrupt controller would execute code in another core which is a CPU. You don't have to remember, just I recommend rewriting everything into txts, and then make a script to search for a word every new section you create a txt. I didn't even memorize anything from the book, I just know some stuff in the commonsense part of my mind, I hope you will know more for the reader.

I read till half of Volume 3 and then skimmed the rest
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/developer/articles/technical/intel-sdm.html

- I watched some of https://www.youtube.com/c/WhatsACreel videos because I was doing a chapter and had 30 day breaks between reading that so I could understand better. I recommend doing that too, but I don't know how to tell you when to stop and question your thinking to watch a video; I'm sorry.

Davy Wybrial's assembly language tutorial to watch after all that of watching:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wLXIWKUWpSs&ab_channel=DavyWybiral
The Intel Software Developer Manual's section called 'Operation Section':

- "a register name enclosed in brackets implies the contents of the location whose address is contained in that register."

How to Start Coding Assembly on Windows (MASM)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lCjbwLeLNfs&ab_channel=CharlesClayton

Again, I'll come back to here (this post, and as well as my future posts) and try to educate everyone, so my knowledge is equal with everyone reading.

Comment: `[]` definitely aren't "functions, which return."  In the context of assembly language, a function is something you call with a `call` instruction.  `[]` in MASM is part of the addressing-mode syntax, as part of a single instruction.  No function, no return involved.  I think that's just bad wording which should be fixed but is separate from the later points you're trying to make.  Which have separate problems:

Comment: You're only looking at the case of a register name inside `[]`.  With numeric literals like `mov eax, [1234]` or a label like `mov eax, L1`, MASM *does* ignore the brackets.  See [Confusing brackets in MASM32](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25129743) - apparently `mov eax, 1234` really is equivalent if you don't use `dword ptr` or `ds:`.  This question is tagged NASM, though, where brackets are *always* meaningful and never optional.

Comment: I edited this question's title to make it clearer it's specifically about NASM syntax.  (Since there are other answers here which say things that are only true for NASM syntax, not MASM.)  This answer was already kind of off-topic since the question was tagged NASM, and this answer only looked at cases with a register inside the `[]` so it's not correct for MASM.

Comment: It's great that you want to contribute and share links to tutorials that you found helpful, and a question like this is likely to be one that beginners look at.   (Although the x86 tag wiki https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info is where collections of links are *supposed* to go; I may take a look at some of those tutorial links and add them if they look good.  I don't go looking for new x86 tutorials myself since I already know how it works.)  Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: But it is important to actually answer the question you're posting under correctly, and without misleading statements about "functions" and "returning", or about "*This would return a decimal number when in hex the number ends with the hexadecimal FF.*"  The numbers in registers are in binary; hex and decimal are just different ways to represent them in source code and debuggers.  No actual conversion is taking place when `mov al, [esp]` itself executes, only during assembly and when later code at run-time prints the number as a string.

Comment: Also, `push 0FFFFh` is a 32-bit operand-size push, not 16-bit.  See [How many bytes does the push instruction push onto the stack when I don't specify the operand size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45127993).  It will assemble to the `push imm32` form https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/push.  It's non-standard terminology to say that's "pushing memory"; normally that would mean pushing a memory source operand like `push dword ptr [1234]`, not an immediate like `push 123` where the value pushed is a constant that's part of the machine code, not loaded as data.  (Only stored as data by push)

Comment: I came from CharlesProxy and python3/js (explains function).  I did just want to say the brackets actually do just get the value of the byte address written inside a register or the address as is. I'll write about the confusingness of writing in machine code so people can just slide into knowing machine code if they have the knowledge of the word 'syntax'., confidently! Again, thank you for posting questions that answer my big post. Also, I would like to state for the readers, the [] in hex machine coding is the modrm byte getting defined. I'll come back to edit a lot of my answers in future

Comment: There you go, it would be much better to start off your answer by saying that the presence and contents of `[]` tells the assembler what memory addressing mode you want it to encode in the ModRM byte (and optional SIB and/or disp8/disp32 bytes).  The correspondence to machine code is a useful angle that other answers on this question haven't already explained.  And it would give you something to replace the nonsense of calling it a "function" or saying it "returns".  In `mov [eax], ecx`, the memory operand is a write-only destination, for example.

Comment: Thank you, I wrote a new beginning update. I was going to go in depth like that in the future to edit this post; but now seemed pretty good as well. That is just a fraction of what the post in the future will be about.

Comment: Since you still didn't fix any of the problems I pointed out in your answer, I did it for you so I could remove my downvote.

Comment: I'm grateful for the help; thank you!

Comment: Your last edit about src and dst seems to only make sense for `mov` or other write-only instructions.  Instructions like `add [rdi], eax` both read and write the memory-destination operand.  I think the clearest way to explain it is that "memory at that address is an operand for the instruction", whether that's a source, destination, or RMW destination.

Comment: If you plan this - "So, this can be an ultimate guide to assembly" - the answer to a specific question is not the best place. You can create other questions, you directly answer yourself as a FAQ, or create community wikis.

Answer (score 0):

It indicates that the register should be used as a pointer for the actual location, instead of acting upon the register itself.