# Source Index in assembly

Tags: assembly, nasm, 16-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What do the brackets mean in x86 asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm)

I've been confused about this for a while. What is the difference between "si" and "[si]"? (This is using 16-bit NASM syntax)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm Same question, pretty much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`si` refers to the register `si`. `[si]` refers the address pointed to by `si`.

```
mov ax, si    //  Copy the "si" to "ax".

mov ax, [si]  //  Load the value stored at address "si" into "ax".
```

Comment: so si, is basically the address, and [si] is the value pointed to by this address?