# Assembly Square Brackets

Tags: assembly

I've always wondered what the difference between

```
mov esi,eax
```

and

```
mov [esi],eax
```

was.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What do the brackets mean in x86 asm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm)

Answer (score 18):

`mov esi,eax` writes the contents of register `eax` to register `esi`.

`mov [esi],eax` writes the contents of register `eax` to the memory address specified by register `esi` (for example, if `esi` contained the value 0x1234, `eax` would be written to address 0x1234).

Comment: I always think of the square brackets as meaning dereferencing the value held in the register.