# ASM 8086 : Reading the value of a variable is different from the value assigned to the variable

Tags: variables, assembly, x86-16

I'm writing a little program in Assembly 8086 and I have to use variables.

So I have a variable that is defined in the data segment :

```
myVar BYTE 3,0
```

Afterwards in my code I have to acces the variable and use it's value. But the program did not work like expected. So I searched the error in my code and I found that when I acces "myVar", the value is different from the value I assigned to it.

When I print the contents of "myVar" it prints 173 instead of 3 :

```
xor dx, dx
mov dl, myVar
push dx
CALL tprint
```

"tprint" is a function I wrote, that will display the number passed as argument via the stack. So in this case it will print the content of the DX register.

When I put 3 in dx and then print it, it prints 3, so "tprint" works fine :

```
xor dx, dx
mov dl, 3
push dx
CALL tprint
```

So the problem is that **when I move the contents of the variable "myVar" in the DL register, the wrong value is put in DL (another value than the value assigned to "myVar")** :

```
xor dx, dx
mov dl, myVar ; DL != 3 --> why???
```

I really don't understand this behaviour, I searched a lot of sites and they all do it this way, why does it works fine for them and not for me?

Remark : The "tprint" function is a function for printing signed numbers using two's complement method.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try making it `mov dl, [myVar]` with the brackets. i'm not sure what assembler you are using but you might be loading the address instead of the value

Comment: *mov es,ax ; put this in es*. And where did you put this in `ds`?

Comment: @rkhb : Thanks! That was the problem! :)

Answer (score 0):

When you move a value from a register, you want to use brackets to move the actual value and not the memory address. So for

```
mov dl, myVar
```

you're likely moving just the pointer instead of the value.

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm)