# Squared Brackets in x86 asm from IDA

Tags: assembly, ida

I used IDA Starter to dissassemble a Windows program, and there is something I don't understand in the resulting assembler code:

```
mov eax, dword_4033CC[eax*4]
```

My question is, what the purpose of the **squared brackets** is.

I found this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm), that is also about squared brackets, but I believe that this is a different context.

Comment: It means the same. It's a slightly confusing syntax variation, you usually see that as `[dword_4033CC+eax*4]`.

Comment: Ah, that makes much more sense, thank you. Is there a usecase where this confusing syntax should be preferred?

Comment: If you want your assembly access to static arrays to look like C, e.g. `arrayname[ecx*4]`, and you're using an assembler that supports that syntax, then use this syntax.  Otherwise don't.