# Offset before square bracket in x86 intel asm on GCC

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, gnu-assembler, intel-syntax

From all the docs I've found, there is no mention of syntax like `offset[var+offset2]` in Intel x86 syntax but GCC with the following flags

`gcc -S hello.c -o - -masm=intel`

for this program

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char c = 'h';
    putchar(c);
    return 0;
}
```

produces

```
    .file   "hello.c"
    .intel_syntax noprefix
    .text
    .globl  main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    push    rbp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
    .cfi_offset 6, -16
    mov rbp, rsp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
    sub rsp, 16
    mov BYTE PTR -1[rbp], 104
    movsx   eax, BYTE PTR -1[rbp]
    mov edi, eax
    call    putchar@PLT
    mov eax, 0
    leave
    .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1) 9.3.0"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

I'd like to highlight the line `mov BYTE PTR -1[rbp], 104` where offset `-1` appears outside the square brackets. TBH, I'm just guessing that it is an offset, can anyone direct me to a proper documentation highlighting this ?

Here is a similar question: [Squared Brackets in x86 asm from IDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49176047/squared-brackets-in-x86-asm-from-ida) where a comment does mention that it is an offset but I'd really like a proper documentation reference.

Comment: you should be able to assemble/disassemble it along with the [rbp - 1] version and compare the machine code and disassembly to see how they compare.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's just another way of writing `[rbp - 1]`, and the `-1` is a *displacement* in technical x86 addressing mode terminology<sup>1</sup>.

The GAS manual's section [on x86 addressing modes](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html) only mentions the `[ebp - 4]` possibility, not `-4[ebp]`, but GAS does assemble it.

And disassembly in AT&T or Intel syntax confirms what it meant.   x86 addressing modes are constrained by what the machine can encode ([Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400)), so there isn't a lot of wiggle room on what some syntax might mean.  (**This syntax was emitted by GCC so we can safely assume that it's valid**.  And that it means the same thing as the `-1(%rbp)` it emits in AT&T syntax mode.)

Footnote 1: The whole `rbp-1` effective address is the *offset* part of a seg:off address.  The segment base is fixed at 0 in 64-bit mode, except for FS and GS, and even in 32-bit mode mainstream OSes use a flat memory model, so you can ignore the segment base.  I point this out only because "offset" in x86 terminology does have a specific technical meaning separate from "displacement", in case you care about using terminology that matches Intel's manuals.

---

**For some reason GCC's choice of syntax depends on `-fno-pie` or not.**   https://godbolt.org/z/iK9jh6  (On modern GNU/Linux distros like your Arch system, [`-fpie` is enabled by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43367427/32-bit-absolute-addresses-no-longer-allowed-in-x86-64-linux).  On Godbolt it isn't).

This choice continues with optimization enabled, if you use `volatile` to force the stack variable to be written, or do other stuff with pointers: e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/4P92Fk.  It applies to arbitrary dereferences like `ptr[1 + x]` from function args.

- GCC `-fno-pie` chooses `[rbp - 1]`  and `[rdi+4+rsi*4]`
- GCC `-fpie` chooses `-1[rbp]` and `4[rdi+rsi*4]`

IDK why GCC's internals choose differently based on PIE mode.  No obvious reason; perhaps for some reason they just use different code paths in GCC's internals, or different format strings and they just happen to make different choices.

Both with and without PIE, a global (static storage) is referenced as `glob[rip]`, not `[RIP + glob]` which is also supported.  In both cases that means `glob` *with respect to* RIP, not actually RIP + absolute address of the symbol.  But that's an exception to the rule that applies for any other register, or for no register.

---

**GAS `.intel_syntax` is MASM-like, and MASM certainly does support `symbol[register]`** and I think even `1234[register]`.  It's more normal for the displacement.

Comment: MASM BNF: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/masm-bnf-grammar?view=vs-2019

Comment: @Hritik: That's only somewhat relevent; GAS syntax is patterned after MASM in general, but they are definitely separate assemblers.  Outside of addressing-mode syntax, their directives are totally different, and GAS doesn't have what MASM calls "variables".  Also, I didn't even find details of MASM addressing mode syntax in that BNF with some quick searching; can you quote whatever part of it was relevant here?