# What's the point of lea edx, 0[0+rax*4]?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

What does this instruction do? Does it change the value of edx to 0?

```
lea edx, 0[0+rax*4]
```

Comment: No, read the manual for `LEA`.  It's a copy-and-shift.

Comment: No, it's putting rax*4 into edx.  Very similiar to `mov edx,eax; lsh edx,2;`, but the flags might be different.

Comment: @Robert McKee: It is called `shl`. And `lea` does not alter any of the status flags.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't. The `lea` (load effective address) instruction is used to put a memory address into the destination.
For example, here, you are going to put `0[0+rax*4]` in `edx`.
Syntax:

> `lea destination, source`

This will help you: https://www.aldeid.com/wiki/X86-assembly/Instructions/lea
Also this: [What do the brackets mean in x86 asm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2030366/what-do-the-brackets-mean-in-x86-asm)