# LEA & MOV instruction comparision

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, mov

**Instruction 1:**

```
LEA DX, MESSAGE ; Move the address of MESSAGE in register DX
```

**Instruction 2:**

```
MOV DX, OFFSET MESSAGE ; Move the address of MESSAGE in register DX
```

### Questions:

- Are the above instructions equal? They seem to work similarly, but I have just started programming assembly so I can not say.
- If both of them are similar, then which one of above is the better way to do the above task?

Note: 
I have already read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: They are only equivalent if MESSAGE is a global variable.  LEA starts to pay off when the variable is stored on the stack or is an element of an array.  You get a multiply and an add for free.  A C compiler really likes LEA.  An assembly programmer not so much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my 32-bit system, the instructions match opcodes like this:

```
8d 15 c8 90 04 08       lea    0x80490c8,%edx
ba c8 90 04 08          mov    $0x80490c8,%edx
```

So you use a whole extra byte when the code is loaded into memory if you use `lea`.

I found a reference to AMD chips at one point having lower latency for `lea` than for `mov`, but only by one clock cycle (and this will be immaterial if the data is not in L1 cache).  I am not sure if that result holds for recent processors.

I have found `lea` useful when trying to add an offset to a base address like this:

```
lea message(,%esi,2), %ecx  # put address of message + 2 x ESI in ECX
```

whereas I can't do this:

```
mov $message(,%esi,2), %ecx  # fails on bad syntax
```

and this produces the wrong result:

```
mov message(,%esi,2), %ecx  # puts _content_ at address, not address, into ECX
```

at least in my assembler (GNU as).

Comment: Latency is not very meaningful when the instruction has no input dependencies.  It starts a new dependency chain for that register.  `mov reg, offset label` is always better, except in 64-bit code where RIP-relative LEA is useful for PIC code, or code loaded outside the low 32 bits (RIP-relative LEA is better than `mov r64, imm64`, but worse than 5-byte `mov r32, imm32` which is usable in position-dependent 64-bit code on Linux.)