# Instruction with LEA and MOV lead to same result - why?

Tags: assembly, instructions

For testing purposes I have written some x86 assembly code:

```
lea  ebx, [esi]
```

I changed the line and wrote:

```
mov  ebx, esi
```

and the program does exactly the same. Why?

In **esi** , there is stored the address of a string. In the first line, I stored the address of the address of the string, right?  And in 2 line, it should store only the address of the string.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea), Amit Singh Tomar wrote that

```
 mov eax ,var == lea eax [var]
```

and when I read and applied that to my case, then I was a little bit confused.

edit: 
I also try to translate that two lines above into pseudo-C code and it looks like this (I assume that ebx and esi are pointers):

```
 (1st line with lea):

 unknownType *ebx = &(*esi)  // since the brackets mean dereferencing, 
                             // I use the dereferencing operator * 
                             // and since lea is equal to the 
                             // address of operator, I came to this result


 (2nd line with mov):
 unknownType *ebx; 
 ebx = esi ;                 // in the second case, ebx would point also 
                             // to the address of the string
```

But this would not be the same, right?

Comment: Because they are the same. They are the same in your pseudo-C too. The `&` eats the `*` so `&*esi` is just `esi`.

Comment: The main reason that you would typically use `LEA` over `MOV` is that you can perform some arithmetic functions using an `LEA` that would require more instructions using a `MOV`.

Answer (score 2):

In the original 8088/8086, I don't think there was any difference and I wondered the same question.  Maybe one was a byte shorter or executed in a cycle less.

However, since the 80386, the effective addressing modes are expanded.

```
mov  ebx, 8[esi*4]
```

With that, `lea` is significantly more useful since there is no single-instruction way to do

```
mov  ebx, 8+ esi * 4      // illegal
```

However, this is perfectly valid and useful:

```
lea  ebx, 8[esi * 4]      // useful and legal
```

Comment: While more limited, the 8086 also had other addressing modes  besides a single register.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation into pseudo-C is correct (assuming `unknownType *esi;` above the code shown).  What you haven't realized is, again in pseudo-C, that

```
&(*x) == x
```

for *all* valid pointers `x`.  You have *not* taken the address of the address of the string; you have only taken the address of the string.

Comment: I somehow feel that this misses the point of the actual question...  Unless I misunderstand the OP, the real question is about differences between `LEA` and `MOV` rather than the pointers in the C code.  I could be wrong, of course.