# Determine if instruction has indirect memory operand

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, intel-pin

Looking at PIN's [Inspection API Page](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/53271/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__GEN__IA32.html#gd3b5f975c84b126531b38930b94b5544) there is a method called `INS_IsLea()` which returns true if the current instruction is a `LEA` isntruction. This is useful, but I need to determine if one of the instruction operands are indirect references. For example:

```
MOV rax, (%rdi)
```

I'd like to be able to determine that the second operand is in fact an indirect reference, but there does not seem to be a method available for this.

Comment: Have you tried looking at an instruction reference? If you examine the machine code you will detect patterns (in fact they are documented) that can tell you this.

Answer (score 1):

[INS_OperandIsMemory()](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/53271/Pin/html/group__INS__BASIC__API__IA32.html#g4e3ee4b5d8346e8f32e5154a720ab093) if you just want to check if one of the operand is a memory operand.

Note that the second argument, `n`, indicates the operand number (0-indexed) in Intel syntax, e.g.

```
; rax = destination op; rdi = source op
mov rax, [rdi] ; rax = op #0 ; rdi = op #1
```

Comment: So even if the operand indirectly calls memory through a register, `INS_OperandIsMemory()` will return true on that operand?

Comment: @TypeKazt: `MOV (%rdi), %rax` is as direct a memory reference as it's possible to write.  IDK what you mean by "indirect" in this case.  Normally the terms direct vs. indirect apply to jumps, where a direct jump has the destination address encoded in the instruction (as a relative offset), while indirect jumps set `RIP = register` (register-indirect `jmp *%rax` aka `jmp rax`) or `RIP = [memory]` (memory-indirect `jmp *(%rsi)` aka `jmp QWORD PTR [rsi]`.)

Comment: If anything, an implicit memory reference is the special case that I'd worry about detecting, like `lodsb` or `MASKMOVDQU xmm1, xmm2` (stores to `(%rdi)`).  Or `push`/`pop`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are looking for two cases:

1. If the an operand is a register containing a memory address. This is used for indirect jumps or calls. Can be detected via `INS_IsIndirectBranchOrCall(ins)`
2. If the second operand is a memory location used for arithmetic or move operations. Can be detected by `(!INS_IsBranchOrCall(ins) && (INS_MemoryOperandCount(ins) > 0))`

*NOTE:*
`lea` instruction just loads a memory address into a register. It never actually access the memory address. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea). `INS_IsLea` returns true is the instruction opcode is `lea`. Hence it will return false for `MOV rax, (%rdi)`

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing here because I have never heard about this library before reading this question, but...

I think it follows that if one of `INS_IsMemoryRead()`, `INS_IsMemoryWrite()` is true, it has to have an indirect memory operand.

Also, from different angle, `INS_MemoryOperand*()` functions inspects the operands.