# How to do the address calculation?

Tags: assembly, memory, x86, hex, att

I saw this case from a website:

```
cmpl $0x0,-0x20(%ebp)

jne xxx (program terminated   so -0x20(%ebp) == 0)

cmpl $0x1,-0x1c(%ebp)

jne xxx (program terminated   so -0x1c(%ebp) == $1)
```

then:

```
lea -0x18(%ebp),%ebx

mov -0x4(%ebx),%eax
```

The website said  %eax = -0x4(%ebx) = -1c(%ebp) == $0

So I don't know why -0x4(-0x18(%ebp)) will equal to -1c(%ebp)
Please help, thank you!

Comment: 0x18 + 0x4 = 0x1c.   (In decimal, 24+4 = 28).  Is that all you're asking?

Comment: it sounds like the website is trying to convey that you can read the same memory location from two different base addresses stored in registers ebx and ebp, but who knows you did not provide enough info.

Comment: Does it really say that -1c(%ebp) is 0, or is that a typo? Because in the comment at line 4 of the code, it says that  it is 1.

Comment: @Rafael the `ebx` is loaded from `ebp` base -0x18 by `lea`, I think the provided info is sufficient. It's just wrong (the resulting value referenced by [ebx-4] is 1, not 0).

Answer (score 2):

> So I don't know why -0x4(-0x18(%ebp)) will equal to -1c(%ebp) Please help, thank you!

The literally taken `-0x4(-0x18(%ebp))` means nothing in x86 assembly syntax, so it can't equal to `-1c(%ebp)` either.

So it depends, what you understand under *"-0x4(-0x18(%ebp))"*.

There are two logical ways how to evaluate that (guessing what you meant).

1) dereference `ebp-0x18`, and use that value from memory (unknown from your question) as memory address, adjust it by -4 and dereference that address again = that makes no sense together with rest of your question text and code provided, so if you understand it like this, you are going in wrong direction.

2) calculate value `ebp-0x18`, then add another `-0x4`, then dereference that value as memory address (load value from memory) = that's the more sensible one, correlating with the other stuff you posted. I.e. only one dereferencing happens. It's not making that expression valid ASM syntax, it just makes sense when evaluated like this.

Then the final address is equal to `ebp - 0x18 - 0x04`, which can be simplified to `ebp - 0x1C`. As Peter Corder commented, it's as simple as 24 + 4 = 28 (0x18 + 0x04 = 0x1C).

If you did understand it as described in 1), then you probably misunderstood [`lea`](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_153.html) instruction? There are already some SO questions about it:
[What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658294/4271923) (there are several good answers, each adding some details)
[What is the difference between MOV and LEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea)

In summary, the `lea` does use the same syntax for memory operand as `mov`, but after it will calculate the memory address (in the same way as `mov` instruction would), it stops there and puts the address value itself into destination register as result. It doesn't contact memory chip for value (no dereferencing). The `mov` instruction continues onward, fetching the final value from memory, and storing that into destination register.

Finally as prl commented, going by the first part of code the memory value at address `ebp-0x1c` is 1, not 0. Must be either typo on your side, or by the web author. Maybe in first version he did use -0x1c for `lea`, and then the `mov` would fetch 0 from `ebp-0x20`. Then made it less obvious by introducing third offset -0x18 and forgot to adjust `mov` offset to -8 or result to 1? Just guessing.