# Does lea in "lea eax, [eax*4]" load the value?

Tags: assembly

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17346124/6949852):

> `lea eax, [eax*4]   == shl eax, 2        ; but without setting flags`

So, I think `lea` loads the **value**(not **address**) of `eax` here and `lea` does the following things:

1. access the value stored in `eax`
2. `<<2`
3. load the calculated value into `eax`

But [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1699778/6949852) says:

> `LEA` loads a pointer to the item you're addressing

Does the two conflict? If `lea` can only `Load Effective Address`, how does it `shl` the value? Where do I understand wrong?

Comment: See [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1658310/16673): LEA, the only instruction that performs memory addressing calculations but doesn't actually address memory.

Comment: @Suma I have read this QA before asking the question. But I am not sure can I say "`lea` in my question load the value(not address)"

Comment: the "effective address" of `[eax*4]` is eax*4, if you load eax with eax*4 this is pretty much "multiplying by 4", which is exact the same like `shr eax,2` does. (without setting the flags, but that's already said in the comment)

Comment: @Tommylee2k Thanks. But IIUC,  `[eax*4]`  still needs the value stored in `eax` to complete the multiplying, right? Or what you mean is, what [eax*4] does is not belong to `lea`,  `lea` only needs the final effective address of  `[eax*4]`?

Comment: You could have just tried this with a value that wasn't a legal pointer and see if it faulted, or with a location that didn't point to itself and look at the resulting value in a register.  **`lea` is a shift-and-add ALU instruction; it doesn't touch memory.  [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597375)**.  It uses memory-operand syntax and machine-encoding because the CPU can already decode addressing modes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does lea in “lea eax, [eax*4]” load the value?

no it doesn't:

I think what confuses you are the brackets '[ ]'

`[1234]` is the "value at address 1234", the "effective address" of it is 1234 (brackets removed)

so `LEA EAX, [4*EAX]` loads the effective address of `[4*EAX]` which is `4*EAX`

The content of `EAX` is (of course read), the value in memory at `[4xEAX]` isn't

in fact `LEA <reg>, [something]` is pretty much the same like `MOV <reg>, something`, while `LEA` can do some basic arithmetics (x2, x4, x8, adding offset), and `MOV` can't

Comment: But how can `[eax*4]` be done without loading/accessing the value of `eax`? I think `eax` in `[eax*4]` is its value, rather than its address.

Comment: `eax` **is** accessed. Memory at address `eax*4` is not (which is what `mov` would do).

Comment: @陳 力 don't mix "the value of eax" (which is eax, and has no address :) ) and "the value of [eax]"

Comment: @Tommylee2k Ok, let me re-organize the question:    But how can `[eax*4]` be done without loading/accessing the value of *eax* (AKA, `[eax]`)? I think *eax* in `[eax*4]` is its value(`[eax]`), rather than its address(`eax`).

Comment: `[eax]` with the brackets means content of **memory** at address `eax`. The difference between the `mov` and the `lea` is that the **memory** is not accessed, not the register's value which of course is. You can think of the `[]` as the `*` operator in C, and the `lea` as the `&` operator.

Comment: `"eax"` is a register, to access it's value no memory has to be read. `"[eax]"` is the content of the memory eax is pointing to (NOT "the value of eax" !! )

Comment: Thanks, @Jester . I think I didn't misunderstand [eax] and eax. "The difference between the `mov` and the lea is that the memory is not accessed, not the register's value which of course is" may be the key to solve my confusion, but I used to think `access the memory == achieve value`, just as what you said in the front "[eax] with the brackets means **content of memory** at address eax". Can you explain more about the difference between "access it's value" and "read memory"? Thanks!

Comment: `eax` is always accessed. If you do `mov eax, [eax*4]` that's roughly `eax = *(eax*4)` hence memory access. If you do `lea eax, [eax*4]` that is `eax = &*(eax*4)` where the `&` and the `*` cancel so you get `eax=eax*4`

Comment: @Tommylee2k Ok, so I mis-use the terms...(I read some articles say "register have two property: value and address" in the past).  Can you give me some cases which memory is accessed?(Like what I said above, I always thought achieve value == access memory, because in c, `*p` just achieve the value stored in address)

Comment: @Jester Thanks, nice example!

Comment: @陳力: registers don't *have* addresses.  They can *hold* pointer values, which *are* addresses.  But pointers are just a special kind of integer in assembly language.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks. Now I know the pointer value is also the content of register. But whose address? As you have said, *registers don't have addresses*. In other words, now that register have no address, how can the assembler find the content from the pointer value(AKA addresses)

Comment: @陳力: Go read [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597375) again.  LEA is a shift-and-add instruction with register sources.  It doesn't matter whether the values are valid pointers or not; LEA doesn't care about anything pointing to anything.