# Round up number to biggest quarter in VB

Tags: vba, vb6

i make mini calculation and need to round the result to the biggest quarter 
example :

if result 
1.12 be 1.25
1.32 be 1.50
1.52 be 1.75
1.80 be 2.00

Answer (score 1):

You can find a good answer here (posted by sehe):

[VBA: Round up to the nearest multiple of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18678106/vba-round-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-a-number?rq=1)

For your need just change the type of the second paramter into double:

```
Public Function RoundUp(dblNumToRound As Double, lMultiple As Double) As Double
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this example.You can use something like this:

[Round a decimal to the nearest quarter in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2826262/round-a-decimal-to-the-nearest-quarter-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I hope this link will solve your problem. [link](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?64997-Rounding-to-nearest-25)

Answer (score 0):

to round to the biggest quarter you first add 0.24 and then round down to a quarter

to round down to a quarter you first multiply by 4, round the number down, and then divide by 4

```
'1 form with
'  1 textbox       : Name=Text1
'  1 commandbutton : Name=Command1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Command1_Click()
  Dim sngVal As Single
  sngVal = Val(Text1.Text)
  sngVal = sngVal + 0.24
  sngVal = sngVal * 4
  sngVal = Fix(sngVal)
  sngVal = sngVal / 4
  Caption = CStr(sngVal)
End Sub
```