# How to round value UP to nearest factor of a number

Tags: algorithm, math, factorial

There are several questions on here how to round a value to a known multiple. For example there is this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407012/c-rounding-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-a-number) but that shows how to round a value to a specified multiple (e.g. round 9 to multiple of 5 will yield 10). I want to round a value up to the nearest factor of a given number. For example lets says I want to round up a value to the closest factor of 48.

```
Factors of 48: 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, 16, 24, 48
```

If my value is 9 I would want to round up to 12. The only way I know to do this is with brute force:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        const int clock = 48;
        int value = 9;

        while( value < clock && (clock % value) != 0) {
            value++;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
}
```

This works fine but it's not clever or efficient, at least I suspect that to be the case.
Is there a better way to round a number up to a factor of a base number other than brute force?

Comment: Clarified the problem statement and addressed why the supplied reference duplicate question isn't applicable.

Comment: Lame that this was closed as a dupe but the referenced duplicate question and solution do NOT address my issue. David, did you read my actual question or base your decision on the title alone?

Comment: Came here looking for the same. Disappointing to find this incorrectly closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private int UCLN(a, b) {
return (b==0)? a:UCLN(b, a%b) } // first input a>b
```

function Main:

```
int u = UCLN(clock, value);

return clock / ((clock/u) / (value/u));
```