# Round int to nearest greater int ending with 0 (C language)

Tags: c, rounding

**Let's say I have 43, I want to round it to 50**

More examples:
41 would be 50
26 would be 30
21 would be 30
57 would be 60

I know there's a round() function, but I think it rounds up with a smaller number if the original number ends with 5 and less...

My code:

```
int total = nomber1 + nomber2;
int roundedTotal = 0;
int control;

if (total % 10 == 0) {
    control= 0;
} else {
    control = roundedTotal - total ;
}
```

Don't pay too much attention to the calculations. All I need is to know how I can round up *total* to the greatest number ending with 0.

Comment: Please take a gander at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3407012/c-rounding-up-to-the-nearest-multiple-of-a-number

Comment: Hint: what will happen to the number if you divide by 10 ?

Comment: What result do you want for an input of 40?

Answer (score 3):

Using integers,

```
total = ((total + 10) / 10) * 10;
```

For instance `40` would give `50`. If `40` should remain `40`

```
total = ((total + 9) / 10) * 10;
```

Answer (score 1):

> Round int to nearest greater int ending with 0
>
> All I need is to know how I can round up total to the greatest number ending with 0.

OP's code is close.

```
int round_greater_int0(int x) {
  int least_decimal_digit = x%10;  //  -10 < least_decimal_digit < +10
  if (least_decimal_digit >= 0) {
    return x - least_decimal_digit + 10;  // may overflow
  }
  return x - least_decimal_digit;
}
```

`round_greater_int0(40)` --> 50.  This is what OP is asking for, yet I suspect this is not what OP wants.

---

`double round(double)` is a function for floating point math, best not use with an integer problem.  Many subtle issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using plain calculations and an `if`.

- Just do a `total % 10` to get the difference from the immediately lesser multiple of 10. 
  eg: `22`  -> `22 % 10 = 2`
- Subtract it from the number and add 10 to it to get the nearest higher multiple of 10. 
  `22- 2 + 10 = 30`.

In case you want even the multiples of 10 to be converted to next highest multiple of `10`, just move the calculation out of the `if` loop.

```
int c = 2;
int x = 18;
int total = x + c;

if(total % 10 != 0) {
  total = total - (total%10) + 10;
}

else {
}

console.log(total);
```