# How to convert an integer to variable length byte string?

Tags: python, integer, bit-manipulation, endianness, byte

I want to convert an integer (`int` or `long`) a big-endian byte string. The byte string has to be of variable length, so that only the minimum number of bytes are used (the total length length of the preceding data is known, so the variable length can be inferred).

My current solution is

```
import bitstring

bitstring.BitString(hex=hex(456)).tobytes()
```

Which obviously depends on the endianness of the machine and gives false results, because 0 bits are append and no prepended.

Does any one know a way to do this without making any assumption about the length or endianess of an `int`?

Comment: Does this only need to work for an `int`, or does it need to work for a `long` as well?

Comment: For `long` as well, I forgot about this. I will edit the question.

Comment: This can be done simply in any version of Python without external dependencies -- in any case, you want a BYTEstring, not a BITstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.7 or later then you can use the `bit_length` method to round the length up to the next byte:

```
>>> i = 456
>>> bitstring.BitString(uint=i, length=(i.bit_length()+7)/8*8).bytes
'\x01\xc8'
```

otherwise you can just test for whole-byteness and pad with a zero nibble at the start if needed:

```
>>> s = bitstring.BitString(hex=hex(i))
>>> ('0x0' + s if s.len%8 else s).bytes
'\x01\xc8'
```

Comment: `bit_length` seems to be a clean solution (though I'm on Python 2.6 on Debian). `(i.bit_length()+7)/8*8` rounds up the length to a length that is dividable by 8, am I right?

The endianness problem also still exists.

Comment: I found an [explanation for the rounding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403631/how-do-i-find-the-next-multiple-of-10-of-any-integer). So only the endianness problem remains.

Comment: `uint` is an alias for `uintbe`, so the endianess problem is also solved.

Comment: This was a bit more difficult than it needed to be, so I've added a feature request (http://code.google.com/p/python-bitstring/issues/detail?id=99) so hopefully in the next version you could say just `BitString(uintbe=456).bytes`. :)

Answer (score 6):

Something like this. Untested (until next edit). For Python 2.x. Assumes n > 0.

```
tmp = []
while n:
    n, d = divmod(n, 256)
    tmp.append(chr(d))
result = ''.join(tmp[::-1])
```

Edit: tested.

If you don't read manuals but like bitbashing, instead of the `divmod` caper, try this:

```
d = n & 0xFF; n >>= 8
```

Edit 2: If your numbers are relatively small, the following may be faster:

```
result = ''
while n:
    result = chr(n & 0xFF) + result
    n >>= 8
```

Edit 3: The second method doesn't assume that the int is already bigendian. Here's what happens in a notoriously littleendian environment:

```
Python 2.7 (r27:82525, Jul  4 2010, 09:01:59) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> n = 65539
>>> result = ''
>>> while n:
...     result = chr(n & 0xFF) + result
...     n >>= 8
...
>>> result
'\x01\x00\x03'
>>> import sys; sys.byteorder
'little'
>>>
```

Comment: This assumes that 1 byte equals 8 bits. I don't know if you can make this assumption with regard to the python semantics.

The second method assumes that the integer is already in big-endian.

Comment: @ott: It's quite safe to say that 1 byte equals 8 bits, and Python integers themselves don't have endianness - it's only an issue in how they are stored or transmitted (i.e. it's only a problem if you've incorrectly unpacked `n` from somewhere before getting this far). Both methods look fine to me.

Comment: Actually, it merely assumes that a byte is at *least* 8 bits, which is guaranteed by the C standard, and thus by the C PyBytes type.

Comment: (1) Somebody please show me a machine that's got a non-8-bit byte and isn't in a museum (like Univac 110X (9-bit) or ICL 190X (6-bit)) and has a currently supported Python implementation (2) for any non-negative integer `x`,  `x & 0xFF` and `x % 256` mean exactly the same thing in both C and Python irrespective of the endianness of the host machine.

Answer (score 1):

A solution using `struct` and `itertools`:

```
>>> import itertools, struct
>>> "".join(itertools.dropwhile(lambda c: not(ord(c)), struct.pack(">i", 456))) or chr(0)
'\x01\xc8'
```

We can drop `itertools` by using a simple string strip:

```
>>> struct.pack(">i", 456).lstrip(chr(0)) or chr(0)
'\x01\xc8'
```

Or even drop `struct` using a recursive function:

```
def to_bytes(n): 
    return ([chr(n & 255)] + to_bytes(n >> 8) if n > 0 else [])

"".join(reversed(to_bytes(456))) or chr(0)
```

Comment: The `struct.pack` method doesn't work, because `struct.unpack` requires a fixed length. For the other methods you would also need a reverse function (trivial).

Answer (score 0):

I reformulated John Machins second answer in one line for use on my server:

```
def bytestring(n):
    return ''.join([chr((n>>(i*8))&0xFF) for i in range(n.bit_length()/8,-1,-1)])
```

I have found that the second method, using bit-shifting, was faster for both large and small numbers, and not just small numbers.

Comment: I get an error using this with large integers. e.g. big = 2442323423424323434242335353 => TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer