# How do you generate a random integer in a specified range, divisible by 5?

Tags: java, random, integer

Given a range of integers, how do I generate a random integer divisible by 5 in that range?

I'm using Java

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I can generate a random number using the following: random.nextInt(max - min) + min; However, I don't know how to make the randomly generated integer divisible by 5.

Comment: Have you thought about division and multiplication? Or did you choose to ask here instead?

Comment: So if the range is [3,7] then the only number you can generate is 5?

Comment: If the range is [1,4], what should your program do?

Comment: Make use of modulus operator or multiplying the answer by 5 otherwise do more reading b3fore u ask plz

Comment: another good question lost to the closing power-trip. obviously the question as worded by the OP technically fits the bill, but if the power-trippers were to either (a) look at the attempts by members to answer; or (b) tried to answer it themselves, they would realize that several interested members who have more than a minimal understanding have attempted solutions, discussed why they are not working. if the close voters had any concern for the community one of them would simply edit or request an edit of the question. but closing gives them the satisfaction of pissing on the effort below.

Answer (score 6):

just generate a regular random integer and multiply it by 5!

**details:** generate a random integer in `[0, n)` where `n` is the number of multiples of 5 in your range, then multiply it by 5 and add the lowest multiple to it.

**one-liner:** `System.out.println(rnd.nextInt(max / 5 - (min + 4) / 5 + 1) * 5 + (min + 4) / 5 * 5);` (assuming non-negative and valid arguments)

**credits:** lowest multiple expression `(min + 4) / 5 * 5` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2403917/621338) and expression simplified a bit based on @Thomas's (imo currently incorrect) answer

Comment: "finding lowest multiple and count is tricky .. leaving as exercise for reader" -- funny, but - no, I don't think that will do.

Comment: not by me, and not sure why. But the oneliner _is_ hard to read. Mind some formatting?

Comment: @JanDvorak simplified + operations aligned with the verbal description

Answer (score 1):

This question calls for a multiple of five in a range, not number in the period of five in the range.

This solution handles negatives and range validity.

```
    // because Java's % operator doesn't do what one might expect with negatives

    int lbound = (min+4) - (((min+4) % 5) + 5) % 5;
    int ubound = max - (((max % 5) + 5) % 5);

    if (lbound > ubound) {
        // do something about the range error
    }

    if (lbound == ubound) {

        return lbound;
    }

    int range = ((ubound - lbound)/5) + 1;

    return ((int)(Math.random() * range) * 5) + lbound;
```

Comment: Why not just do `if(lbound > ubound)` for the error detection?

Answer (score 1):

First create a `Random`, and round `low` and `high` to the nearest higher/lower multiple of 5 respectively:

```
Random r = new Random();
low = ((low+4)/5)*5;    // next multiple of 5
high = (high/5)*5;  // previous multiple of 5
```

This may make `low > high`, which is infeasible, so don't proceed any further; or it make may make `low == high`, which may be of no interest whatsover, so you may want to test for that. The code below works correctly either way, because of the +1 and -1: generate a random number in `{low..high}`

```
int randomPart = r.nextInt(high-low+1)+low-1;
```

Then round it upwards to a multiple of 5. The prior shenanigans with `low` and `high` assure it is in range:

```
int nextInt = ((randomPart+4)/5)*5;
```

Comment: This actually doesn't work.

Comment: Have you tried this? What if low = 14 and high = 16?

Comment: Revised it totally ;-)

Answer (score 0):

This method first computes how many numbers divisible by 5 are in the given range. It picks a number between 0 and that count at random, and translates that random number back into the given range by multiplying it with 5 and adding it to the lower bound.

Note that both `lowerBound` and `upperBound` are inclusive.

```java
public static int getRandomDivisibleByFive(int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
    if (lowerBound > 0) lowerBound += 4;
    if (upperBound < 0) upperBound -= 4;

    lowerBound /= 5;
    upperBound /= 5;

    int n = upperBound - lowerBound + 1;

    if (n < 1) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Range too small");
    }

    return 5 * (lowerBound + new Random().nextInt(n));
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Picks a random number between your values and then tests if it is divisible by div. If it is it returns that value otherwise it will have to do at max div-1 iterations to get to a number divisible by div.

In your situation call rBetweenGenerator(min, max, 5)

```
public int rBetweenGenerator(int min, int max, int div)
{
  int res = min + ((new Random()).nextInt(max - min + 1))
  for(int i = res; i < res + div; i++)
  {
    if( i % div == 0 )
    {
      return i;
    }
  } return -1; //error
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the range boundaries are not supposed to be returned if they are not divisible by 5

Comment: whoops thought i saw a question answered earlier about [3,7] returning either 3 5 or 7 fixed.

Comment: uhh... why are you returning `-1` for an error? You should throw an exception if an error occurs.

Comment: If your initial `res` is above the highest valid multiple of 5 then you will return a number greater than `max`.