# Generate a random number in interval [0,360) which is divisible by number 15

Tags: java, random

I am wondering how to generate a number in interval of [0,360) which would be also divisible by number 15. Examples: 0, 15, 30, 45, 50..  I can generate a number in the interval with:

```
    (int)(Math.random()*360));
```

But I don't know how to make sure that the generated number is divisible by number 15.

Comment: Given that your intended integer is `n`, consider the range that `n/15` will fall into. This should then lead to a clear next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO Michal!

One easy way to accomplish this is to generate a random number less than 24 (=360/15), then multiply the result by 15:

```
(int)(Math.random()*24)) * 15;
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking some information from this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341074/how-do-you-generate-a-random-integer-in-a-specified-range-divisible-by-5), you can just generate a random number between the range 0 to 24 and multiply it by 15.