# What does the LEAL assembly instruction do?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

I am a little bit confused about the difference between

```
leal -4(%ebp), %eax
```

and

```
movl -4(%ebp), %eax
```

Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003894/leal-assembler-instruction

Comment: and kind of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: The clue is in the name. Load Effective Address only loads the address.

Comment: I'd advise to read the friendly CPU manual. And you have a choice: from Intel or from AMD.

Comment: @PrateekGupta The tag you added doesn't make sense. It is part of the answer, not part of the question. If the OP had known that tag was apposite, he would have known the answer and not asked the question.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

[LEA](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/LEA.htm) (load effective address) just computes the *address* of the operand, it does not actually dereference it.  Most of the time, it's just doing a calculation like a combined multiply-and-add for, say, array indexing.

In this case, it's doing a simple numeric subtraction: `leal -4(%ebp), %eax` just assigns to the `%eax` register the value of `%ebp - 4`.  It's equivalent to a single `sub` instruction, except a `sub` requires the destination to be the same as one of the sources.

The `movl` instruction, in contrast, accesses the memory location at `%ebp - 4` and stores that value into `%eax`.

Comment: I kind of had that understanding after a while when I saw that it set the eax register to the result.

Answer (score 8):

If you wish to look at this in terms of a different programming language, then:

```
int var;
[ ... ]
func (var, &var);
```

evaluates to the following (Linux x86_64) assembly code:

```
[ ... ]
   4:   8b 7c 24 0c             mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi
   8:   48 8d 74 24 0c          lea    0xc(%rsp),%rsi
   d:   e8 xx xx xx xx          callq  ... <func>
[ ... ]
```

Since `%rdi` / `%rsi` are the 1<sup>st</sup> / 2<sup>nd</sup> arguments, you can see that `lea ...` retrieves the *address* `&var` of a variable, while `mov ...` loads/stores the *value* `var` of the same.

I.e. in assembly, the use of `lea` instead of `mov` is similar to using the address-of `&` operator in C/C++, not the (value of) a variable itself.

`lea` has far more uses than that, but you explicitly asked about the difference between the two.

For illustration: `mov` with a memory operand always performs a memory access (load or store), while the memory operand to `lea` is merely treated as *pointer arithmetic* - i.e. the address is calculated and resolved but no memory access happens at the instruction itself. These two:

```
lea 1234(%eax, %ebx, 8), %ecx
movl (%ecx), ecx
```

result in the same as:

```
movl 1234(%eax, %ebx, 8), %ecx
```

while the following:

```
leal (%eax, %eax, 4), %eax
```

multiplies the value in `%eax` with five.

Answer (score 1):

Equivialent to `LEA` in Intel syntax, load effective address (long?).