# Simple Leal instruction

Tags: assembly, x86-64

Just to be sure that I've understood this instruction.

Hopefully not a duplicate.

Does `leal 3(%rdi), %eax` first deference the address and then compute? So we're not computing the address.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11212444/what-does-the-leal-assembly-instruction-do

Comment: It is simply computing `rdi+3`. And yeah, you bet it is a duplicate of a gazillion questions.

Comment: `lea` never dereferences by definition.

Comment: @fuz Thanks, it's all clear now.