# What do parenthesis and tab mean in gas assembly langurage x86

Tags: assembly, syntax, x86, gnu-assembler, att

I am working on some gas assembly code, and I cannot find the meaning of parenthesis and tab in the code. Take some examples:

```
cmpl $99,-4(%ebp)

movl $1,(%eax,%edx)

leal 0(,%edx,4),%eax

 pushl %ebp
 movl %esp,%ebp
 subl $2,%esp
 movl $0,tab
```

Does parenthesis means math operation? If so, what does (%eax,%edx) and 0(,%edx,4) mean? Is tab a contant in gas assembly?

Comment: For these instructions look up the instruction itself.  The keyword for what you are looking for ("the meaning of...y") is **syntax**.  So search the net for "leal syntax"

[ leal 0(,%edx,4),%eax ]
==
[ eax = '' + 0 + 4*edx ]

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32704450/547981) explains the effective address syntax, I am closing as duplicate. As for `tab`, that's just a symbol defined elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know regarding parenthesis in Assembly it means moving a register stored as a pointer into the location that is in the parenthesis for instance:

mov (%eax) / moves the value stored in the pointer to eax