# LEA operation with 8086 assembly

Tags: x86, x86-16

can anyone help me understanding the following instructions-

```
LES SI,DATA1
MOV DI,OFFSET DATA2
MOV BX,[SI]
MOV CX,[DI]
MOV[SI],CX
```

Comment: If you need help for MOV, you're not ready for LEA. If you need help for LEA see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: no idea if les/lea?

Answer (score 3):

`LES` is not `LEA`. `LES x, y` interprets `y` as a far pointer and loads its data into `ES` (a segment register) and `x`.

The instruction sequence as given is strange though, because `ES` is not actually used.

Anyway, the instruction sequence (if the `[SI]` are changed to `ES:[SI]`) is: given a far pointer (`DATA1`) and a variable (`DATA2`), move the contents pointed to by `DATA1` into `BX` and replace them by what is stored currently at `DATA2` (which will also be in `CX`).

Answer (score 1):

You can just look up an assembly instruction page, and it would explain what each of those instructions do in a simple to understand way; in many ways assembly in its basic, low-level simplicity is easier to understand a single line than in higher level languages.

I can never remember which x86 assembly syntax orders things which way if I haven't used it in a while (the two major x86 assembly syntaxes order the operands in the opposite order), so I won't say the exact result here.

For the first one, I assume that's a typo and you meant LEA instead of LES? LEA stands for "load effective address" if I recall correctly. Its main purpose it to calculate the memory address of something when you want to actually know the address instead of just use the address.

(edit)
I had not used LES before, and Google wanted to redirect me to LEA, hence my above statement. I will leave the above though so you can benefit from that too.
(/edit)

MOV moves data from one place to the other. The operands in the MOV instructions that are surrounded by [] square brackets mean  you want that memory address instead, so MOV CX,[DI] would be "move the contents of the CX register into the memory location at the address held in the DI register" (or the other way around, [DI] into CX, see above statement about operand order).

I'm not sure on the "OFFSET DATA2" as I don't recall an offset keyword.

Answer (score 0):

corresponds to the following C code :

```
// DATA1 and DATA2 are 'far' pointers to word of 16 bits, let's say they are 'short'
short bx = *DATA1;
*DATA1 = *DATA2;
// the old value of *DATA1 is still available in the BX register.
// and the value of *DATA2 is still available in the CX register.
// also, ES is set to the segment where DATA1 and DATA2 resides.
```

Comment: um.. i think DATA2 is not interpreted as a pointer (because `OFFSET` is used to derive a pointer to it) -- it should just be a plain old integer variable