# Question about lea instruction, IA32

Tags: c, assembly

If I have an IA32 instruction like the following:

```
lea 0x4(x1, x2, x3), %eax
```

What do x1, x2, and x3 represent?
Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [x86 asm: What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Answer (score 4):

If you mean "what is lea for," follow the link in Greg's comment.

If your question is about the syntax and are familiar with Intel syntax (but not AT&T syntax), x1 is the base, x2 is the index, and x3 is the scale (with 0x4 being the displacement). Thus,

```
lea 0x4(x1,x2,x3),%eax
```

is equivalent to

```
lea eax,[x1+x3*x2+4]
```

See [this article](http://asm.sourceforge.net/articles/linasm.html) on SourceForge for more.

Answer (score 0):

They are a *base* register, an *index* register, and a *scale* value. So, it's useful for calculating the address of an element of an array *base* of elements of size *scale* at position *index*, i.e. in C:

```
base[index]
```

where *scale* will be 1 for a *char* array, 2 for a *short* array, ... on typical C compilers for x86.