# What is the lea instruction before a method call doing?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, assembly

In looking at my disassembled code I see a lot of the following:

```
00B442E9  push        4  
00B442EB  push        3  
00B442ED  lea         ecx,[ebp-24h]  
00B442F0  call        Foo::Bar (0B41127h)
```

I understand pushing the parameters before the call, but what's the `lea` doing here?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `thiscall` calling convention used by Visual C++ for x86, the `this` pointer is passed in the `ecx` register.  This `lea` instruction copies the `this` pointer into the `ecx` register before calling the member function.

You can read all about the `lea` instruction in the Stack Overflow question ["What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Comment: Is there a reason it isn't just pushed onto the stack as well?

Comment: I do not know.  g++ `thiscall` just pushes `this` onto the stack after the last argument.  If I had to guess, someone probably did a performance analysis and decided that preemptively enregistering `this` yielded better performance in common use cases.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's just an optimized form of

```
mov ecx, ebp
sub ecx, 24h
```