# x86 Intel Assembly -- Are these two statements equivalent?

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

Very simple question here...I'm trying to wrap my head around assembler and curious as to whether these to operations are equivalent:

```
mov [ebx], 5
```

and

```
lea esi, ebx
mov esi, 5
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. `mov [ebx], 5` puts the value 5 into the address pointed to by ebx (at least that's the general idea of what it should do. MASM, for one, will reject it because it doesn't know what size of destination you want, so you'd need `mov byte ptr [ebx], 5`, or `mov word ptr [ebx], 5`, etc.)

The second copies ebx into esi, then copies 5 into esi. It doesn't (even attempt to) move anything into memory. What you're (apparently) looking for would be more like:

```
lea esi, ebx
mov [esi], 5
```

Again, you'll run into the same thing though: you'll need to specify `byte ptr` or `word ptr`, or whatever. Also note that in this case, it's rather wasteful to use `lea` -- you're doing the exact equivalent of `mov esi, ebx`. You normally only use `lea` when you want to do a more complex address calculation, something like: `lea esi, ebx*4+ebp`.

Comment: +1 Deleted my answer, though I think you're still missing `[ebx]` in the `lea` instruction.

Comment: @user786653: There may be *some* assembler that requires brackets for the `lea` (and MASM, for one, might well allow but ignore them) but they're not normally required.

Comment: Well I can only talk about the assemblers I regularly use NASM (which requires it) and GAS (which requires it in AT&T mode (`lea (%ebx), %esi` rather than `lea %ebx, %esi`)  as well as `.intel_syntax` same as NASM).

Comment: @user786653: how odd -- I'm nearly certain I remember a conversation a few years ago with one of the developers of NASM where he said that it only used the brackets when there was going to be a reference to memory.

Comment: Well, `lea` _does_ take a reference to memory [Vol. 2A 3-579](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html), it doesn't do any dereferencing, though. Hence why it's often used for simple arithmetic calculations that don't actually involve memory references e.g. `lea eax, [eax+eax*2]` for `eax *= 3`.

Comment: The source operand for `lea` [uses memory operand syntax and machine encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers/46597375#46597375) even though it's a shift-and-add instruction.  It's totally weird and non-standard to omit the brackets, except in the MASM-syntax case of `lea esi, symbol_name` because `symbol_name` without `OFFSET` is a memory operand.  NASM won't assemble this: `foo.asm:1: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands`.  Using `lea esi,[ebx]` to copy a register is totally pointless vs. `mov esi,ebx` anyway...

Comment: But note that `lea esi, symbol_name` is also useless (in 32-bit mode) compared to `mov esi, OFFSET symbol_name` which is faster and 1 byte shorter.  In 64-bit mode, RIP-relative LEA is useful.

Answer (score 2):

You can do

```
lea esi, [ebx]
mov [esi], 5
```

and this will be equal to your first snippet.

Comment: Thanks! Out of curiosity, what would "lea esi, ebx" do?

Comment: As already pointed out to in other responses, there is no such thing as `lea esi, ebi`. `lea` itslef will (l)oad (e)ffective (a)ddress, that is you need to provide address argument rather then just register. Hence `[ebx]`.

Comment: Check this for details on `LEA` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Answer (score 0):

No, they aren't, `mov [ebx], 5` moves 5 to the memory location designated in `ebx`, while

```
lea esi, ebx
mov esi, 5
```

Calculates the memory address into `esi` (in this case it just copies `ebx` to `esi`) and then moves 5 into `esi`, not writing to memory.