# lea assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, x86, att, addressing-mode

I Just want to make sure I am reading this right:

```
movl 12(%ebp), %edx
leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax
```

I read the first line as: `edx = [epb + 12]`, and the second line as: `eax = edx + edx*4`

Can anybody clarify?

Also, what if I had the following two lines:

```
leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax
leal (%edx, %edx, 2), %eax
```

Once the second line is executed, would the `eax` register be overwritten?

And the `eax = edx + edx*4` is multiplying the address by 4? Or the contents of the address by 4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction?rq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right. The `LEA` instruction is used to Load (the) Effective Address, and can be used for address arithmetic and sometimes also ordinary arithmetic, if you don't need the flags.

Answer (score 9):

The instruction `movl 12(%ebp), %edx` means: `edx = [ebp + 12]`. This is a memory reference (a read operation) to the address `ebp + 12` whose contents (a double word) are read to `edx` register.

The instruction `leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax` means: `eax = edx * 5` (which is a simplification of `eax = edx + edx * 4`). The `leal` instruction doesn't do memory references. It only performs arithmetic with registers.

As an answer to your second question: Yes, `eax` would be overwritten because the instruction `leal (%edx, %edx, 2), %eax` means `eax = edx * 3` which is different from the first instruction, `eax = edx * 5`.