# How does leal instruction work?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm given these `leal` instructions and I have to fill in what they mean.
I've been trying to study how the `leal` instruction acts, but I've been having difficulty finding relevant material around the web. What I found is

```
leal (src1, src2), dst  //dst = src2 + src1
```

This info doesn't give enough information, because the `leal` instruction is far more complex than that.

How is this looking?

Assume `%eax` holds the value x and `%ecx` holds the value y. Fill in the table.

```
%edx =  x + 6___________leal 6(%eax),%edx
%edx =  x + y___________leal (%eax,%ecx),%edx
%edx =  x * 5y___________leal (%eax,%ecx,4),%edx
%edx =  9x + 7___________leal 7(%eax,%eax,8),%edx
%edx =  4y + 10___________leal 0xA(,%ecx,4),%edx
%edx =  x + 3y + 9___________leal 9(%eax,%ecx,2),%edx
```

Comment: I would use intel syntax so it's easier to read. eg. `lea edx, [eax + 6]`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lea assembly instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153282/lea-assembly-instruction)

Comment: @phuclv: If you want a canonical duplicate for LEA on non-pointer values, [Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597375) is my attempt.  (But it's more about LEA vs. MOV, than how to actually use it for math).  If anything, I like this Q&A better than the one you linked. Both the answer and the question, and I might consider making that a duplicate of this.  So many LEA questions, it's a wasteland of confusion with so many scattered small answers that explain one part.  You have to really understand CPUs and asm for it to make total sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I would do is translate the above att syntax over to intel syntax as a first step since that is much more intuitive to analyze.

```
lea edx, [eax + 6]            
lea edx, [eax + ecx]          
lea edx, [eax + ecx * 4]      
lea edx, [eax + eax * 8 + 7]  
lea edx, [ecx * 4 + 10]       
lea edx, [eax + ecx * 2 + 9]
```

Even if you know nothing about the assembly syntax you can look at the above can kind of figure out what they mean. You can mentally map this as an assignment statement in your favor programming language: the thing you are *assigning to* is on the left-hand side and the value *being assigned* is on the right-hand side. Now it's just a matter of substituting in the registers with your `x` and `y` values:

```
edx = x + 6
edx = x + y
edx = x + y*4
edx = x + x*8 + 7 => x*9 + 7
edx = y*4 + 10
edx = x + y*2 + 9
```

Comment: +1 for the Intel syntax. AT&T syntax kills the assembly programming. :)