# what is leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax means?

Tags: assembly, x86

[lea assembly instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153282/lea-assembly-instruction)

at above page it says

The instruction `leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax`       means:`eax = edx * 5`

but how ?

as i know  `%edx` is base next `%edx` is index  and 4 is scale

i.e.    disp(base,index,scale).

Comment: The question you linked already explains it. It's just `edx+edx*4`which is of course `edx*5` (you know, `1+4=5`)

Comment: @Jester can u explain step by step how `edx+edx*4` become `edx*5` (how 4 becomes 5 )?

Comment: That's elementary school maths ...if you get 1 apple and 4 more apples you will get 5 apples ... what's unclear?

Comment: @Jester   I know but its written format is confusing ...                    can you please explain these as example   `nums dd 1,2,3,4 `

Comment: `lea` does not access memory, it only does `eax = edx * 5`. It does not need `nums dd` and it doesn't use any of the numbers there.

Comment: how come a + a*4 not equal to 5*a? use Intel format: `lea eax, [edx+edx*4]`, it's much less confusing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lea assembly instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9153282/lea-assembly-instruction)

Answer (score 3):

> disp(base,index,scale).

You *know* how this instruction works (base + index * scale) but your troubles come from the fact that you keep considering the first component to always be an address ("i.e. any adress in memory address space") and the second component to always be an index ("i.e. anything of 0,1,2.....").

To the CPU that executes this instruction the contents of `%edx` can have any meaning you choose! It's always **just a number** and that's precisely why we use instructions like `leal (%edx, %edx, 4), %eax` to calculate `%eax = %edx * 5`.

Comment: I like to explain `lea` by saying it's a shift-and-add instruction that just happens to use the addressing-mode syntax and machine-code encoding.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `disp(base,index,scale)` gives address:

```
base + scale * index + disp
```

therefore, address `(%edx, %edx, 4)` is interpreted as

```
disp := 0
base := %edx
index := %edx
disp := 4
```

In together, it gives:

```
%edx + %edx * 4 + 0
```

which gives `%edx * 5`.

Now, `leal` is used for address assignment. It assigns the above address to `%eax`, hence you get `%eax := %edx * 5`.

---

This is commonly seen, because the scaling factor `scale` can only be 1, 2, 4, 8, hence there is no way to multiply %edx by 5 directly. Similarly, if want to get `%eax = %edx * 3`, we have to do `leal (%edx, %edx, 2), %eax`.

Comment: can you explain it with example.                                                                     I mean with assigning numbers to %edx

Comment: `(%edx, %edx, 4) `  first  `%edx`  is base address  i.e. any adress in memory address space , second `%edx` is index  i.e. anything of 0,1,2.....   and scale is `4` then how it is interpreted as  `%edx * 5`?

Comment: No, both `%edx` are the same, just numbers (which could be a memory address but are most likely not in this case). So you have the base `%edx` and you are adding the index `%edx` with scale `4`, i.e. you are adding the index `%edx*4` to the base `%edx`, which makes `%edx+%edx*4` which is, using simple math, `%edx*(1+4)`, which makes `%edx*5`. With numbers: Assuming `%edx == 10` then you have `%edx := %edx + %edx * 4`, `%edx := 10 + 10 * 4`, `%edx := 10 + 40`, `%edx := 50`.