# Reading a number into a register from stdin? Loading a scanf result

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I am currently busy with assembly and ran into the following problem:

I'm trying to get a number that has been typed into the eax register. First i present a string which asks for input and then someone has to enter a number.

I've used the following code, but I don't understand every bit of it. Please note the comments in the code.

I know absolutely nothing happens now with the number, except that is has been moved into eax. What i do want to know is why i must use leal: why and what does it do? and why do i need to push eax back on the stack?

```
.text
string1: .asciz "Please enter a number\n"
input: .asciz "%d" 

.global main
main:
       # Editor's note: this code is broken / unsafe; missing push %ebp here
  movl %esp, %ebp
  
  push $string1          # prompt string
  call printf            #print the string
           # no add $4, %esp here: 4 bytes still allocated on the stack

  leal -4(%ebp), %eax   # ????
  pushl %eax            # the thing you pushed in eax is now pushed on the stack?
  pushl $input          #the number 
  
  call scanf      
  
  popl %eax
  popl %eax       # the number that has been entered is now in eax
  
  call end
  
end:
  push $0
  call exit
```

Comment: Note that `push %esp` could replace that `lea` / `push %eax` because ESP is pointing at the 4 bytes reserved by the first `push $string1`.  No need to use a frame pointer at all, so the broken `mov %esp, %ebp` could be removed. (Broken because you're not saving/restoring EBP, but in standard calling conventions it's call-preserved).

Comment: Also, this code isn't safe for modern systems that require 16-byte ESP alignment before calling functions.  (e.g. i386 System V ABI on Linux, but not most other OSes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling functions, so you pass parameters to them on the stack. One integer is returned to you in `eax`, rest is via input-output pointer parameters, again, on the stack. Check out [**x86 calling conventions**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions).

#### Edit 0:

The `leal` instruction stores *effective address* of some temporary variable (that's where `scanf` puts your integer value) into `eax`, then you pass it to `scanf` on the stack. Take a look here: [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/x86-asm-whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Comment: Okay, but what does leal exactly do?