# What is R_386_32 type symbols in C runtime library?

Tags: assembly, compilation, x86, binary, crt

I read [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12412923/4305223).
As far as I understand, `R_386_32` is for static data, and `R_386_PC32` is for function. right?

However I'm still confusing about the usage of `R_386_32` type symbol.
See below example.

***Example 1***

```
readelf -a --wide /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o | grep R_386_32
0000000c  00000901 R_386_32               00000000   __libc_csu_fini
00000011  00000b01 R_386_32               00000000   __libc_csu_init
00000018  00000c01 R_386_32               00000000   main
```

***Example 2***

```
readelf -a --wide /usr/local/lib/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/5.5.0/crtbegin.o 
00000001  00001501 R_386_32               00000000   __TMC_END__
00000010  00001601 R_386_32               00000000   _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
00000031  00001501 R_386_32               00000000   __TMC_END__
00000049  00001701 R_386_32               00000000   _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
000000a1  00001901 R_386_32               00000000   _Jv_RegisterClasses
```

***Question***

1. In ***Example 2***, `R_386_32` typed datas are automatically added to *Application*
   while in compile time?
2. If yes, can I reference those data in my code?
   For example, Can I make the *Application* that printf the value of `_Jv_RegisterClasses`?
3. In ***Example 1***, Why *main* is `R_386_32` type?
   I think It should be `R_386_PC32`, because it is not static data, it is function.

Comment: You are looking at *relocations,* not *symbols.*  Relocations are just what the assembler generates when it wants to refer to a symbol whose value is unknown; it's an instruction to the linker to fill in the correct value at link time.  `R_386_32` just means “paste the value of the symbol as 32 bit here.”  There is no way to say if the symbol used is for data or text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking at *relocations,* not *symbols.*  Relocations are just what the assembler generates when it wants to refer to a symbol whose value is unknown; it's an instruction to the linker to fill in the correct value at link time.  Relocations are not symbol types; each symbol can be referred to through an arbitrary amount of relocations of arbitrary type.  Note also that the symbol table does not know what type of datum a symbol refers to, if at all.  A symbol is just an address and a name.

The relocation type `R_386_32` just means “paste the value of the symbol as 32 bit here.”  There is no way to say if the symbol used is for data or text.  This is used for example, if you load the address of a symbol or perform an absolute memory access.  Both of these instructions generate a `R_386_32` relocation:

```
mov $foo, %eax       # move value of symbol to register
mov foo, %eax        # perform absolute memory access
```

On the other hand, the relocation type `R_386_PC32` subtracts the value of the instruction pointer (**p**rogram **c**ounter) from the symbol and pastes that.  This relocation type is mainly used for direct jump and call instructions:

```
jmp foo              # jump to foo
call foo             # call foo
```

In general, there is no way to guess what section a symbol is defined in from looking at relocations.  Indeed, the relocations do not give any information about this at all and an object file cannot demand that an external symbol refers to data or text.  For defined symbols, you can find out what section they are in by running the `nm` utility.  Symbols marked `t` or `T` are text, `d` or `D` are data, `r` or `R` are read-only data, and `b` or `B` are BSS.

For your second question:  yes, you can.  Use C code like this to print the value of `_Jv_RegisterClasses`.  Note that the value of a symbol is the address of the variable it refers to.

```
extern const void _Jv_RegisterClasses;  /* or any other type */

printf("%p\n", &_Jv_RegisterClasses);   /* print value of symbol */
```

Comment: A PC-relative relocation is highly unlikely to be anywhere outside the text segment; it's pretty rare to write `dd target - $` or something; but for PIC code you might well make them all offsets relative to some other symbol.  So you can *guess* that `R_386_PC32` means it's a rel32 in code, but you can't know for sure.   Of course you can have executable code in various sections, like `.init` as well as the normal `.text` section, inside the text segment.

Comment: @PeterCordes Not that unlikely.  Suppose you want to make a function table in PIC code that shouldn't need relocation during linking.  A bunch of `dd function - table` do the trick quite well.

Comment: `void` is the one type you can't use here.

Comment: @RossRidge It is legal and does compile.

Comment: @fuz Hmm... I guess you're right for C, it's not legal in C++ though.