# Decoding and understanding assembly code

Tags: assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decoding and understanding assembly code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13391171/decoding-and-understanding-assembly-code)

I am a beginner with c and assembly code, we have an "bomb" assignment (written in c)which calls methods that require certain passwords, but the code is not visible and I need to determine the correct password by looking at the assembly code.

The code indicates the password for this method is 6 numbers, which is passed as "input" to method puzzle_1 (I am trying to avoid triggering ).

I can't understanding assembly code.

What is the answer to this question?

I think this puzzle_1's keyword is array.

```
08048db4 <puzzle_1>:
8048db4:        push   %ebp
8048db5:        mov    %esp,%ebp
8048db7:        sub    $0x38,%esp
8048dba:        lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
8048dbd:        mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
8048dc1:        mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048dc4:        mov    %eax,(%esp)
8048dc7:        call   804897e <read_six_numbers>
8048dcc:        movl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
8048dd3:        jmp    8048df9 <puzzle_1+0x45>
8048dd5:        mov    -0xc(%ebp),%eax
8048dd8:        mov    -0x24(%ebp,%eax,4),%eax
8048ddc:        mov    -0xc(%ebp),%edx
8048ddf:         sub    $0x1,%edx
8048de2:        mov    -0x24(%ebp,%edx,4),%edx
8048de6:        add    $0xbf,%edx
8048dec:        cmp    %edx,%eax
8048dee:        je     8048df5 <puzzle_1+0x41>
8048df0:         call   8048d93 <denied_nextstep>
8048df5:         addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)
8048df9:         cmpl   $0x5,-0xc(%ebp)
8048dfd:         jle    8048dd5 <puzzle_1+0x21>
8048dff:          call   8048d73 <allow_nextstep>
8048e04:        leave  
8048e05:        ret
```

Comment: The trick to understanding assembly is to learn it.

Comment: And also learning how to use a debugger...

Comment: It's not polite to ask a question again if it's been closed. The community has already told you to put some more effort into the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to learn assembly. A quick primer so you can discover the answer on your own is to step through the instructions one by one with a table that maps the mnemonic to its purpose, a table for the different addressing modes, a calculator for mapping hexadecimal to decimal if you can't do it in your head, and a good ol' internet connection for doing some research when you don't understand something.

For example, here is the first few instructions...

```
; Push the value in %ebp register onto stack
8048db4:        push   %ebp

; Copy the value from %esp register into %ebp register
8048db5:        mov    %esp,%ebp

; Subtract 0x38 from %esp register
8048db7:        sub    $0x38,%esp

; Wasn't sure about this one, so I looked it up
; (Looking up things you're not sure of is a 
;  good way to learn about those things.)
; http://stackoverflow.com/q/1658294/31671
8048dba:        lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax
```

Answer (score 2):

There are about three categories to understand here:

1)   computer architecture:

- register architecture / Instruction Set Architecture

  - arithmetic (such as a+b)
  - bitwise logical such as a OR b
  - conditions  (such as a == b or a < b ) with different flags for signed & unsigned

    - `cmp    %edx,%eax`
  - jumping

    - unconditional: `jmp`
    - conditional: `je`; `jle` etc.  -- related to *condition codes* or *flags* or *Status Register*
    - subroutines: `call`;
  - memory architecture
  - different kinds of *addressing modes*

    - immediate `sub    $0x38,%esp`
  - memory address calculation `lea    -0x24(%ebp),%eax`
  - CISC type: can you 'add' directly to a memory address
    `addl   $0x1,-0xc(%ebp)`
  - RISC type - READ / MODIFY / WRITE back

2)  syntax of the language

- instruction src, dst   vs. instr dst, src
- encoding of *labels*, comments, assembler directives, decimal and hexadecimal numbers

3)  Concept of local stack frame, local variables and pointers

- `push ebp;   mov esp, ebp;`
- calling conventions used in this particular example (global register, general purpose registers, or stack (frame)
- items not fitting to registers are typically passed with pointers

The best way to learn this would be using a instruction level debugger showing memory & register contents and optimally highlighting changes between each instruction. And of course reading the Instruction Set Architecture manual and Application Binary Interface specification.

Good luck!

Comment: Great answer, would have loved this when I started. :)