# How does lea instruction get the operand's address?

Tags: assembly, x86

How does this work exactly? I know that lea is efficient compared to using add/mov instructions because it doesn't go through the ALU or set any flags. So how is lea getting its addresses? What makes it better than add/mov?

Comment: Why is x86-lea a tag?

Comment: @harold: Michael Petch and I [think it shouldn't be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction/12805360?noredirect=1#comment86713234_12805360) (because of lack of scope for future non-duplicate questions) but I'm not going to undo all the tagging right away.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LEA instruction uses the effective address (EA) part of the CPU to do certain kinds of arithmetic without using the ALU. The EA module can do very specific kinds of arithmetic that is used for address calculation, but can also be used for other things if what you need is one of the things it specifically provides.

By not using the ALU for this EA calculation, the ALU can be busy doing something else at the same time and you can avoid a pipeline stall.

Comment: I saw another post similar to this on stackoverflow by another person. 

"The fact that LEA goes through the address generation logic instead of the arithmetic units is also the reason why it used to be called "zero-clocks"; it takes no time to execute because address generation has already happened by the time it would be / is executed."

Do you know what he means by "it takes no time to execute because address generation has already happened by the time it is executed"?

How is an address generated by execution time?

Comment: The CPU runs instructions in a "pipeline", instead of doing them one by one and completely finishing one instruction before starting the next. The pipeline means the CPU can be preparing for future instructions at the *same time* as it is finishing the execution of the current instruction. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_pipeline if you want to read more about this.

Comment: This is maybe true on in-order Atom (pre Silvermont), but not anything else recent.  Atom does run LEA earlier in the pipeline than normal ALU instructions, with implications for latency, but it needs its inputs ready earlier. All modern x86 CPUs have out-of-order execution, including even the current generation of Xeon Phi, so this doesn't.  Also, in-order Atom has two ALU ports and 2-per-clock throughput for `add`, so the only effect of using LEA is a latency difference, not throughput.  http://agner.org/optimize/

Answer (score 5):

The idea that `lea` doesn't go through the ALU is outdated and has been wrong for over a decade. It goes through one of the ALUs - of which there will be several, and that is extremely unlikely to be a bottleneck. It actually takes time. It's not faster than an `add`.

But that doesn't mean it isn't useful. Unlike `add`, it can have a destination that differs from both inputs, so it can save a `mov`, and it can take an extra constant so you can do two `add`s and a `mov` all in one. The scaling is also nice, and all combined you can do something like `a = b * 9 + 5` all in one `lea a, [b + b * 8 + 5]`. Such "complex" forms of `lea` are often slower than than simpler 2-operand forms of `lea`.