# LEA or LOAD integer?

Tags: assembly

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Having just started assembly language I would like if someone could tell me the difference between using:

`load R1,one[R0]` rather than `lea R1,1[R0]`

when using the value in R1 only as an increment value. For the former, the data is given (one data 1) whereas for the latter data it is not.

Comment: I think it's weird to talk about assembly without specifying the CPU.

Comment: I apologise, I'm very new to this. I'm using Sigma16. Only dealing with 16 bit words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case you are loading *data*, in the second case you are loading an *address*.

E.g. if R0 contains 0x1000:

```
      addr   data
R0 -> 0x1000 0x42
             0x48
             0x49
             0x43
             0x30
```

then `load R1,1[R0]` will load 0x4849 into R1 (assuming the load instruction is a 16 bit load, and the architecture is big endian), whereas `lea R1,1[R0]` will load 0x1001 into R1.