# 8086 TASM: Illegal Indexing Mode

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16, tasm

I am writing an 8086 assembly program that needs to compile through TASM v3.1. I am running into an error I can not seem to fix.

My data segment has the following set up for the purposes of keyboard input:

```
paraO Label Byte
  maxO DB 5
  actO DB ?
  dataO DB 5 dup('$')
```

What I am trying to do is get the first character entered, so the first byte of dataO:

```
lea dx, dataO
mov bl, [dx]
```

However, when I attempt to compile, I get this error:

```
**Error** h5.asm(152) Illegal indexing mode
```

Line 152 is "mov bl, [dx]"

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
If it matters, I am running TASM through DOSBox (My laptop is running 64-bit Win7)
Google hasn't come up with any helpful answers.
I can post the entirety of my code if necessary.

Comment: Get official documentation from intel.com or amd.com. See the operand addressing modes.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86#Addressing_modes) has a useful summary of x86 & x86-64 addressing modes.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15353616/illegal-use-of-register-in-indirect-addressing/15355230#15355230

Answer (score 9, accepted):

pretty sure the reason is that you can't use the DX register as a pointer.

try instead using [si], [di] or [bx]:

```
 lea bx, data0
 mov al, [bx]
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved this, I was unaware that BX had to be used. Thanks