# mmap in nasm using int 0x80 on linux x86

Tags: linux, nasm, mmap, system-calls

I'm writing a small library in nasm for linux and I'm implementing malloc atm.

The C representation of the code would look like

```
void * malloc(int size) {
    return mmap(0, size, 3, 34, -1, 0);
}
```

Now I have to convert that to assembly, but I'm stuck at loading the arguments.

```
mov eax, 90
; load args (help)
int 0x80
; move adress to eax
```

I'd like to know how to convert the C code into asm. In most cases the arguments of a syscall are mapped in the same order as in assembly, but mmap takes 6 arguments, and the kernel takes a maximum of 5 arguments.

I'd also like to know where the returned value is stored.

So, how should I implement it.

**Update:**

code:

```
section .data
mmap_arg:  ; ugly
  .addr:   dq 0
  .len:    dq 512
  .prot:   dq 3
  .flags:  dq 34
  .fd:     dq -1
  .offset: dq 0

mmap_test:
  mov eax, 90
  mov ebx, mmap_arg
  int 0x80
```

It seems like its working, but when I load something at the address of eax, I get a segfault. When I replace eax with ebx, it runs without errors. <strike>Can someone confirm that the returned address is in ebx, or that I'm writing in the .data section when using ebx.</strike>

Gdb shows that only eax gets modified after int 0x80. I'm stuck again. It's gettting late, I'll have a look again at it tomorrow.

Comment: Code your "mmap()" call in C, then compile with "gcc -S".  This will dump assembly output, and show you exactly how the routine is called.  NOTE: not all platforms make Linux syscalls the same way (as you probably already know).  The assembly for one Linux platform might *not* be correct for a different platform.

Comment: Yes, it shows how it calls the mmap function in the library, but in the environment I'm working for (empty initramfs) doesn't have a standard library.

Comment: basically you push a [`mmap_arg_struct`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/mmap.c#L1356) on the stack, palce it's address into ebx and execute the syscall. (http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/)

Comment: Tnx, I'll try it. However it seems a bit strange that I need a struct to allocate memory for a struct.

Comment: well, mmap takes more arguments then fit into the registers, so the arguments must be passed some other way.

Comment: It seems like it's working, but I after int 0x80 I get a value of 0xfffffff7 in eax when allocating 512 bytes. Seems a bit too high. (still debugging)

Comment: Could be, but according to the man pages the address returned on error is -1, and the value of eax changes when I change mmap_arg.len . Edit: Oh you edited your post already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One change, the args definition must be dd, not dq on ia32. The mallocSample function below will return the recently allocated memory into eax.

```
        global  main
        extern  printf

        section .data
mmap_arg:  ; ugly
  .addr:   dd 0
  .len:    dd 512
  .prot:   dd 3
  .flags:  dd 34
  .fd:     dd -1
  .offset: dd 0

        section .text

mallocSample:
        ;old_mmap
        mov eax, 90
        lea ebx, [mmap_arg]

        int $80

        ret

main:
        ;malloc sample
        call mallocSample
        push eax
        push    message
        call    printf
        add     esp, 8
        ret
message:
        db      'our malloc gives address: 0x%x', 10, 0
```

Comment: Thanx, it makes much more sense to store adresses and such in a dword. What is the big difference between `lea a, [b]` and `mov a,b` (except speed)?

Comment: None in this case. You could read about lea/mov differences at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction - I'll edit the above answer to leave that clear.

Comment: What if, I want len to be a variable rather than hard-coded constant value. Which instruction to use?