# IA32 Assembly: lea instruction

Tags: assembly, x86

I know that the sentence I am about to say is probably the best way to become very unpopular on StackOverflow very quickly. I'll say it anyway: Why doesn't this work (completly)?

I was trying to figure out **what the lea/leal instruction does**. The way I understand it, lea/leal finds out the memory address of the first operand and writes this address into the second operand (which might be a register or so).

This part seems to work. When I run the program below it says:

```
The memory address of var is 134518204.
```

However, right after this it says something like "memory access error". **pushl (%eax)** obviously doesn't work. Why not?

```
.data
    var:    .long 42
    str1:   .string "The memory address of var is %d.\n"
    str2:   .string "At this memory address we find var's value: %d.\n"

.text
.global main
main: 
    leal var, %eax          # Copy the address of var into %eax
    pushl %eax
    pushl $str1
    call printf             # Print str1
    pushl (%eax)
    pushl $str2
    call printf             # Print str2

    # Some stack cleaning should be here :)

    movl $1, %eax
    int $0x80
```

I am not even sure if I got right what lea/leal does. Help is appreciated. ;)

Comment: `movl src, dest` means `dest = src`. `leal src, dest` means `dest = &src` (i.e dest = address of src)

Comment: To be more accurate, `movl` evaluates the source, treats it as an address and moves it's contents to destination.

But, `leal` evaluates the source and moves the evaluated value to destination.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The way I understand it, lea/leal finds out the memory address of the first operand and writes this address into the second operand (which might be a register or so).

Sounds accurate enough. It's used to perform address arithmetic; which can be as simple as just loading an address, but you can also use it to perform multiplication by certain constants.

---

> `pushl (%eax)` obviously doesn't work. Why not?

Your `push` instruction is not referencing the address you think it does: `printf` returns the number of characters written, and that value is returned in the `%eax` register, so `%eax` no longer contains the address of `var`.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually just read that according to the C Calling Convention, %eax will ALWAYS be changed. Seems like I really need to do something else for a while... :D

Answer (score 2):

`lea` is usually (ab)used for calculations: if you just want the address of a global in a register, `movl $var, %eax` is clearer (and a byte shorter) than the `lea`.

Also, to make it clear, the destination operand of `lea` *must* be a register.