# How does the lea instruction interact with esp?

Tags: assembly, x86

I read that for example "lea eax, [ebp - 120]" essentially means

```
mov    eax, ebp
sub     eax, 120
```

Given the example that the esp is at ebp-200, then later in the function

```
lea eax, [ebp - 120]
push eax
call xyz
```

would this mean that the value at ebp-120 is loaded into the eax register, then this 4 byte vaule is pushed onto the stack?  Or does it mean that the esp is decremented further by 120, thereby creating a buffer from ebp-200 to ebp-320, with esp now at ebp-320?

Comment: Your first interpretation is correct.

Comment: `push eax` pushes the contents of the `eax` register onto the stack.

Comment: The code is passing a pointer to a local variable.  Stored in the stack frame of the caller at ebp-120.  Very common.  Doesn't have anything to do with esp, other than at the caller's function entry the esp value needs to be adjusted to make space for the local variables.  The way stack frames work is well described in many tutorials and books.

Comment: Can you guys take a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30007738/how-does-lea-instruction-store-address-of-a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

lea looks more fancy than mov, but in reality it only does part of what mov does: mov calculates the address and dereferences memory, lea just calculates the address.

In your example, eax receives the value stored *in* ebp with 120 subtracted, not the value stored *at the address* which is stored in ebp with 120 subtracted. This value proceeds to be pushed onto the stack. If this assembly corresponded to C code, eax/stack would contain a pointer to some variable.

There is no direct interaction between lea and esp. Unless esp is one of lea's arguments, lea does not read or modify esp.

Comment: I like to explain it by saying `lea` is a shift-and-add instruction that just happens to use memory-address syntax and machine code.