# Simplifying and writing single assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers

given the following assembly instructions

```
mov ax,  bx  
add ax,  di
```

How can I write a single instruction to have the same effect as those two?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that there is an equivalent 'single instruction' for *any* two (or more) instructions. In this case, the solution *appears* to be

```
mov ax, bx+di
```

However, that instruction does not exist. But there is the `lea` command: [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

and so this ought to work:

```
lea ax, [bx+di]
```