# What does lea 0xY(%esp), %esi do?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I dont understand what this code will do

```
lea   0x13(%esp), %esi
```

**%esp** is a stack pointer, **%esi** is index register.

Is 0x13 offset?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm used to the Intel syntax, so I believe this is what's happening:

```
lea esi, [esp+13h]
```

Say `esp` is 0x18000 - the result of this operation will be 0x18013, since you're not actually accessing any memory with `lea`.

Again, I only have experience with the Intel syntax, so my answer may be incorrect. Hopefully this has helped you!