# Questions about LEA in assembly code, x86

Tags: assembly, x86, reverse-engineering

Here are two lines of assembly code

```
mov  0xc(%ebp), %eax
lea  0x14(%eax), %edx
```

I know the first line is the same as the following in pseudo code

```
%eax = 0xc(%ebp)
```

and it's make `%eax` equal to the second parameter. But what is the second line trying to do?

Comment: That's just a sneaky `add`; `edx = eax + 0x14`

Comment: @harold Is this accessing the value at the address of (eax + 14)

Comment: No. `lea` just does a bunch of math, it doesn't access any memory.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction for details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does lea 0xY(%esp), %esi do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23869183/what-does-lea-0xyesp-esi-do)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)