# Dereference a C# by ref pointer in an asm DLL

Tags: c#, assembly, unmanaged, freepascal, calling-convention

I have the following, which works perfectly:

```
procedure ShuffleAry16(var Ary16: TByteAry; MaskLow, MaskHigh: Int64); cdecl; assembler;
asm
  movdqu        xmm0, [rcx]             // unaligned load Ary16
  movq          xmm1, rdx
  pinsrq        xmm1, r8, 1
  pshufb        xmm0, xmm1
  movdqu        qword ptr [rcx], xmm0   // unaligned save Ary16
end;
```

C#:

```
public static unsafe extern void ShuffleAry16(byte* ary, ulong maskLow, ulong maskHigh);
```

I have another case where I need to pass the byte pointer by reference. Let's keep the current method as an example:

```
public static unsafe extern void ShuffleAry16(ref byte* ary, ulong maskLow, ulong maskHigh);
```

I can't figure out how to correctly get the address of ary (RCX) in this case. I tried lea, but it didn't work:

```
  lea           rax, [rcx]
  movdqu        qword ptr [rax], xmm0
```

How do I do this?

Comment: I understand that this may not be possible.

Comment: I don't think that you want `lea` here, from my understanding you should just use `mov` as `ref byte *` is marshaled the same as `byte**`. Should be something like `mov rax,qword ptr [rcx]` (Don't have anything to test with at work)

Comment: That worked, thank you. Please post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you want `lea` here, from my understanding you should just use `mov` as `ref byte *` is marshaled the same as `byte**`.

Should be something like:

```
mov rax,qword ptr [rcx]
```

For reference I searched what was exactly `lea` and while it's made to be used when referencing things in array it doesn't really access anything just compute adresses. This stackoverflow answer was useful to my understanding : [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)