# POPing the address into a register

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64

Is there a way to pop the address of the top of the stack and not the content? I want the address into a register and use it to manipulate program later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AT&T syntax:

```
leaq (%rsp), %rax
```

In Intel syntax:

```
leaq rax, [rsp]
```

or whatever register you need to use. `rax` is provided only as an example. The `lea` command loads the *address* specified into the register, not the *content*. For more information, see [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction)

You also could do this with a simple `mov`:

```
mov %rsp, %rax
```

or

```
mov rax, rsp
```

If you need to actually modify the stack pointer, you can simply add the number of bytes necessary to it.