# What does an lea instruction after a ret instruction mean?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I found x86 `lea` instructions in an executable file made using clang and gcc. 
The `lea` instructions are after the `ret` instruction as shown below.

```
 0x???????? <func>
   ...
   pop %ebx
   pop %ebp
   ret
   lea 0x0(%esi,%eiz,1),%esi
   lea 0x0(%edi,%eiz,1),%edi

 0x???????? <next_func>
   ...
```

What are these `lea` instructions used for? There is no `jmp` instruction to the `lea` instructions.

My environment is Ubuntu 12.04 32-bit and gcc 4.6.3.

Comment: Can you print the binary code, too?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: I suggest to compile your C source code `foo.c` with `gcc -fverbose-asm -O -S foo.c` then look inside the generated assembler `foo.s`. I guess that the `lea` is actually some data in your code segment

Comment: Yeah - some const/static thingy.

Comment: BTW, your Ubuntu is quite old, and your GCC compiler is pathetically old. Current GCC is 5.2.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably not anything--it's just padding to let the next function start at an address that's probably a multiple of at least 8 (and quite possibly 16).

Depending on the rest of the code, it's *possible* that it's actually a table. Some implementations of a `switch` statement, for example, use a constant table that's often stored in the code segment (even though, strictly speaking, it's more like data than code).

The first is a lot more likely though. As an aside, such space is often filled with 0x03 instead. This is a single-byte debug-break instruction, so if some undefined behavior results in attempting to execute that code, it immediately stops execution and breaks to the debugger (if available).

Comment: Thank you very much for your understandable explanations! by rewriting the lea instruction for alignment, it's likely to be variety of things.

Comment: This instruction is merely a very long nop.