# What is the difference between MOV and LEA in terms of retrieving an address

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

What exactly is the difference between mov and lea when I use them to get an address?

Let's say if I have a program printing out a character string starting from its 5th character whose code is shown below:

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov edx, 0x06  ;the length of msg from its 5th char to the last is 6.
    lea ecx, [msg + 4]
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80

section .data
msg db '1234567890'
```

Then, if I swap `lea ecx, [msg + 4]` for `mov ecx, msg + 4`, would it run differently?

I tried both and the outputs appeared to be the same. However, I read from this link, [What's the purpose of the LEA instruction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction),  in the comment section of this first answer, it seemed that someone claimed that something like `mov ecx, msg + 4` was invalid, but I failed to see it. Can someone help me to understand this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: "`mov ecx, msg + 4` was invalid, but I failed to see it" - Have you even tried it? `mov ecx, msg + 4` is not a valid instruction.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and yes, I tried it. As I mentioned in my question, I tried both, and they gave me identical outputs.

Comment: @Mysticial: It's certainly valid NASM syntax.

Comment: @Michael I guess NASM does constant propagation?

Comment: @ Michael: So I can use them interchangeably?

Comment: @Mysticial: `mov ecx, msg + 4` just loads the address of `msg`, plus 4, into `ecx`. I don't see why that's any more special than being able to do `lea ecx, [msg + 4]`.

Comment: @glenjoker: The encoding for `mov` is shorter, but `lea` is more flexible because it lets you do things like `lea ecx, [msg + eax*4]`.

Comment: @Michael Oh ic, so the assembler treats it as memory operand. As someone who only reads assembly output by compilers, I wouldn't have known that since they always inline the address with the `[]`.

Comment: @Mysticial: no, you're thinking of MASM syntax, where it *is* invalid.  In NASM syntax, it's an immediate constant.  (MASM: `mov ecx, OFFSET msg + 4` or something).  Linker relocations allow symbol+displacement, so `symbol + 4` is still a link-time constant.  The exact same thing happens to generate the 4B displacement for `LEA`'s effective address.

Comment: @Michael: Okay, that makes sense. Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ahh... Good to know. Thanks!

Comment: @PeterCordes: Um, wouldn't `mov ecx, msg+4` in MASM syntax mean the same thing as `mov ecx, [msg+4]`? I haven't used MASM/TASM in a while, but that's the way I recall it.

Comment: @Michael: That's probably not valid.  I think you'd need `mov ecx, msg[4]`, or `[msg + 4]`.  MASM allows the square brackets, so IMO you should *always* use them when referencing memory for readability, NASM style.  I haven't ever used MASM.  I only bothered learning anything about it to read/answer SO questions.  I'm not a MASM programmer, I just play one on the Internet.

Comment: `mov reg, label+imm` assembles for me with MASM 6.14 anyway. I didn't bother to look what it assembled _to_.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the absolute address is a link-time constant, `mov r32, imm32` and `lea r32, [addr]` will both get the job done.  The `imm32` can be any valid NASM expression.  In this case `msg + 4` is a link-time constant.  The linker will find the final address of `msg`, add 4 to it (because the placeholder in the `.o` had the +4 as the displacement).  That final value replaces the 4B placeholder when copying the bytes from the `.o` to the linker output.

Exactly the same thing happens to the 4B displacement in `lea`'s effective address.

---

`mov` has a slightly shorter encoding (no ModRM byte), and [can run on more execution ports](http://agner.org/optimize/).  See also https://uops.info/ (Assembled+linked, then disassembled into GAS intel syntax, not NASM.)

```
08049000 <foo>:
 8049000:       b8 00 90 04 08          mov    eax,0x8049000
 8049005:       8d 05 00 90 04 08       lea    eax,ds:0x8049000
```

**Use `mov reg, imm` unless you can take advantage of `lea` to do some useful math with registers at the same time**.  (for example: `lea ecx, [msg + 4 + eax*4 + edx]`)

---

In 64-bit mode, where RIP-relative addressing is possible, using LEA lets you make efficient position-independent code (that doesn't need to be modified if mapped to a different virtual address).  There's no way to achieve that functionality with `mov`.  See [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57212012/how-to-load-address-of-function-or-label-into-register-in-gnu-assembler)  and [Referencing the contents of a memory location. (x86 addressing modes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes/34058400#34058400)

Also see the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) for many good links.

---

Also note that you can use a symbolic constant for the size.  You can also format and comment your code better.  (indenting the operands looks less messy in code that has some instructions with longer mnemonics).

```
section .text
    global _start
_start:
    mov    edx, msgsize - 4
    mov    ecx, msg + 4     ; In MASM syntax, this would be mov ecx, OFFSET msg + 4
    mov    ebx, 1       ; stdout
    mov    eax, 4       ; NR_write
    int    0x80         ; write(1, msg+4, msgsize-4)

    mov    eax, 1       ; NR_exit
    xor    ecx, ecx
    int    0x80         ; exit(0)
    ;; otherwise execution falls through into non-code and segfaults

section .rodata
msg db '1234567890'     ; note, not null-terminated, and no newline
msgsize equ $-msg       ; current position - start of message
```

Comment: Very detailed explanation, and it answers my question perfectly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Really awesome answer.