# Getting the address of a symbol using AT&T x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, att, micro-optimization

I've been messing around with a toy kernel and I'm confused about accessing a symbol's address.

Suppose I'm defining the stack I want to use like this:

```
_stack_bot:
  .skip 4096
_stack_top:
```

I can't load the stack using:

```
movl _stack_top, %esp
```

because that's going to move a 4 byte value starting at the address starting at _stack_top into %ecx, which is incorrect.

Instead I do this:

```
movl $_stack_top, %esp
```

but, I can also do this:

```
lea _stack_top, %esp
```

Both load the same address, and everything works. My question is, is there any difference between the two in this context?

Comment: The `mov` instruction has a shorter encoding and can often run on more ports.  But that's about it.

Comment: In 32-bit code, you don't have the option of using a PC-relative LEA for position-independent code, so there's no benefit to `lea`.  [How to load address of function or label into register](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57212012) is about x86-64, so not really a duplicate despite on paragraph buried in that answer saying *but never use LEA with a `[disp32]` absolute addressing mode (even in 32-bit code where that doesn't require a SIB byte); `mov` is always at least as good.*

Comment: [What is the difference between MOV and LEA in terms of retrieving an address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35475396) uses NASM syntax to ask about the difference between the same two machine-code instructions, `mov reg, imm32` and `lea reg, [disp32]`.  So I think it's a duplicate unless you were asking about source-level differences.  (There aren't any in AT&T syntax either.)