# Why is LEA (Load Effective Address) necessary?

Tags: assembly, x86, linker, nasm, mov

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1699748/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475396/what-is-the-difference-between-mov-and-lea-in-terms-of-retrieving-an-address) yet to find what it is I want.

Firstly, I understand the difference between `lea` and `mov` in terms of the result they can achieve, put simply:

```
mov  eax, ebp   ;put the value in ebp register into eax register
lea  eax, [ebp] ;same as above, and they are equivalent
```

However:

```
mov  eax, ebp+8   ;invalid register set size
lea  eax, [ebp+8] ;calculate in sum of ebp value and 8, then assign it to eax
```

So why is `mov  eax, ebp+8` illegal while `lea  eax, [ebp+8]` is OK? My book says:

> The value that MOV stores into EAX must be computed by the assembler
> (that is, it must in the end be a constant)

But it makes no sense to me! What is meant by **CONSTANT**?  The obvious understanding is that the **CONSTANT** should be calculated by the assembler/linker before the program runs, BUT, think about `mov  eax, [ebp+8]` is a **LEGAL** instruction. The assembler/linker has no way of knowing the value of `[ebp+8]` (`*(ebp+8)` as C lingo) before the program runs!

Comment: Don't the comments under the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665570/11683) of the first question you are linking to answer that?

Comment: @GSerg How could you possible find it LOL

Comment: Note that at least the Go assembler indeed allows you to write `MOVL $8(BP), AX` to generate `lea eax, [rbp+8]`.  Admittedly, it's kind of the odd one out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book seems to only be talking about mov-immediate, like `mov eax, 1234` or `mov eax, foo` (symbol address).

A more complete rule is that the source operand for `mov` has to either be:

- a link-time constant value (mov-immediate)
- or a value that already exists somewhere else (memory or another register).

**`mov` can only copy, it won't feed the data through an ALU before writing the destination.**

---

A memory source operand can use an addressing mode like `[ebp+8]` or `[edx + eax*4 + my_array]`, but that's unrelated to what happens to the data loaded from or stored to that address.  Address-generation is done in a separate part of the CPU (or on original 8086, in a separate phase of microcode processing the instruction).

x86's machine-code format encodes [addressing modes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34058101/referencing-the-contents-of-a-memory-location-x86-addressing-modes) (and register vs. memory source) the same way for almost all instructions, so `mov` doesn't have to do anything special to support `mov eax, [ebp+8]`, it's just like `add eax, [ebp+8]` which also does an add with the data after doing the address calculation and a load.  Only the opcode byte differs between those, specifying what to do with the data, not where the operands are (register vs. memory addressing mode).  (There are [two opcodes for most instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50336269/x86-xor-opcode-differences), one where the source can be memory, one where the destination can be memory.
I'm talking about two memory-source opcodes here.)

The machine code for `lea eax, [ebp+8]` is also the same as those except for the opcode byte.  **The special part of LEA is that it uses the machine-code format for an addressing mode to encode a shift/add instruction that doesn't actually access memory.**  See *[Using LEA on values that aren't addresses / pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46597055/using-lea-on-values-that-arent-addresses-pointers)*

No other instruction can do that so you can never use `eax+3` as a source operand for any instruction.  e.g. there's no way to do `imul ecx, eax+3` with only one instruction.

---

**There are two separate concepts**: where the data comes from for an instruction (immediate, register, or memory addressed by an addressing-mode) vs. what happens to that data (copy vs. imul vs. sub vs. popcount vs. ...).  In that sense, LEA doesn't have a data input, since it doesn't deref the `[ebp+8]`.

LEA just takes the address, like C's `&` address-of operator, which cancels out what would otherwise be a dereference, e.g. `&ptr[3]` is the same as `ptr+3` but with different syntax.  One thing that makes LEA interesting is that x86 ADD can only do `ptr+=3`, modifying a register (or memory) in place, but LEA can copy-and-add like `tmp = &ptr[3]`.

(And with 32 or 64-bit addressing modes, also add a shifted register like `tmp = &ptr[x*4 + 3]`)

---

Somewhat off-topic but maybe related:

Most classic x86 integer instructions are only one or two-operand (*[What kind of address instruction does the x86 cpu have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53325275/what-kind-of-address-instruction-does-the-x86-cpu-have)*).  Although `imul ecx, [edx+8], 123` can do math while writing the result to a register that wasn't an input.   (Unlike most immediate-source instructions, that new-in-186 form of `imul` didn't steal the `/r` field in ModRM as extra opcode bits, so it could have 3 operands including the immediate whose presence is signalled by the opcode.) But still the input to the hardware multiplier is an immediate and a value directly from memory; `imul ecx, edx+8, 123` isn't encodeable.

Comment: Learning assembly without knowing how the CPU exactly works is not enough, because the rule for instructions is just wired. From your answer, I can conclude that the operand for `mov` (or `add` etc) is addressable without knowing the exact address(that explains `[ebp+3]` works but `ebp+3` does not ). And the operands for `lea` can be calculated `out of thin air`!  Can not imagine how **machine code** can be used without extra memory/register to complete the calculation. It is really hard for me to make sense of the rules.

Comment: If `ebp+3` can be calculated using *machine code* in `lea`, why not did the same thing for others like `mov` or `add`. On the other hand, if `ebp+3` can not work, how `[ebp+3]` can?

Comment: @Guichi: As an operand for LEA, `[ebp+3]` is an addressing mode, addressed with the mode and R/M fields of the ModR/M byte (https://wiki.osdev.org/X86-64_Instruction_Encoding#ModR.2FM_and_SIB_bytes); most opcodes imply the presence of a ModR/M byte to encode the operands.  Like this answer was trying to explain, only LEA is special in taking the address calculation, kind of like the `&` address-of operator in C, which can make a dereference not actually deref.

Comment: @Guichi:  There's two separate concepts: where the data comes from (immediate, register, or memory addressed by an addressing-mode) vs. what happens to that data (copy vs. imul vs. sub vs. popcount vs. ...).  In that sense, LEA doesn't have a data input, since it doesn't deref the `[ebp+3]`.  It just takes the address.