# direct memory addressing mode

Tags: assembly, x86, emu8086

Assume a byte has been defined in the data segment

```
DSEG      SEGMENT
    NUM   DB   ?
DSEG      ENDS
```

Then, what is the meaning of the following instructions in terms of addressing mode?

```
LEA     SI, NUM
```

and

```
MOV     NUM, 1AH
```

Since `NUM` is a label for a memory entry (say 1000H), I assume that the first one is interpreted as `MOV   SI, [1000]` and the second is interpreted as `MOV   [1000], 1AH`. So, they use direct memory addressing mode. Am I right?

Comment: `LEA` loads the address of the operand, not the value stored there.

Comment: So the address is `[10000]` in this case. Isn't that?

Comment: `10000H` is more than 16 bits and you are using 16 bit x86 so you are wrong!

Comment: Excuse me... I missed something.... Since the address in `[]` is a logical address is is 16bit wide, e.g. [1000H]. I edited the post.

Comment: In Intel syntax those should be `lea si,[num]` and `mov [num],1Ah`. There're some assemblers which will work even with syntax you used in question, but I dislike them (and they can compile the official Intel syntax too, so there's no reason to not use the `[]`). After you follow official Intel syntax, `lea` is the only exception where using `[]` doesn't mean accessing memory, only address calculation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "direct" addressing... Whatever is enclosed in `[]` is calculated to some number, which is used as an address to access particular byte/word/dword/qword in memory. Inside the brackets can be just fixed immediate (address), or register, or some limited expression like `[ebx + esi*2 + NumArray]`. Anything without `[]` should be just value without accessing memory (but your assembler is trying to be smarter and will fill-in `[]` in some cases for you). In NASM the `mov si,NUM` will load `si` with the value of symbol `NUM` i.e. address of that byte = equal to `lea`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, not quite.

The `LEA` is used to move the *address* into the destination.  So, the address represented by the label `NUM` is moved into `SI`.  This is immediate mode, since you are directly moving a value into a register.

The second one, while it doesn't have a `byte ptr` or `[]`, moves the value 0x1a into the memory location represented by the label `NUM`. This is direct mode since you are using a raw memory address represented by `NUM`.

Comment: Do you mean that `lea` is using immediate addressing and the second one uses direct mode?

Comment: Not really.  LEA doesn't really move data, it just figures out addresses and offsets, allowing you to do some simple mathematics quickly.  Have a look at my answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction

Comment: The second is using direct addressing.

Comment: But don't both instructions technically use direct addressing mode? Only that `lea` doesn't load anything from memory but only stores the effective address and `mov` actually loads something.

Comment: No.  The value of `NUM` in that instruction in machine language will be a static value.  There is no actual reference to memory, so it would be wrong to think of it as direct addressing.

Comment: Assemble it and then use GDB or ndisasm to dump it out or view it with hexdump.

Comment: @David Hoelzer: That `lea` should be immediate addressing mode... because you are moving a `number` or `value` to a register. No matter, who is providing the value (programmer or OS), it is neither register mode nor memory mode. Do you agree with that?

Comment: Ah, good point Mahmood.  I edited to clarify the immediate vs the direct.  He threw me when he asked, "...using immediate *addressing* mode..."