# Understanding pointer assignment in x86-64 Assembly Code

Tags: c, assembly, x86-64, att

I am trying to understand assembly code. I am stuck in the portion where the pointer is assigned and the code after `leaq` command

This is my C code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int x=50;
    int *y=&x;
    return 0;
}
```

This is my corresponding ASSEMBLY code:

```
.file   "AssemlyCode.c"
    .def    __main; .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .text
    .globl  main
    .def    main;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .seh_proc   main
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    .seh_pushreg    %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    .seh_setframe   %rbp, 0
    subq    $48, %rsp
    .seh_stackalloc 48
    .seh_endprologue
    call    __main
    movl    $50, -12(%rbp)
    leaq    -12(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, -8(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
    .seh_endproc
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.4.0"
```

Comment: `int y=&x;` is invalid. `y` is not a pointer

Comment: Sorry i made a rookie mistake while writing the code..... I have corrected it now

Comment: Easier to read example: pass a pointer to a local to an external function.  Then you can enable optimization without everything optimizing away.  [See source + asm on the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/N6ESby), which strips out all the `.seh_` and other directives that set metadata for the object file.

Answer (score 6):

```
    leaq    -8(%rbp), %rax
    movl    %eax, -4(%rbp)
    movl    $0, %eax
    addq    $48, %rsp
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

1. `leaq` saves address of variable `x` on the stack to register `rax`. Variable `x` is automatic variable on the stack, hence it address is calculated as offset from register that holds stack frame pointer(`rbp`).
2. `movl eax` to stack saves `argc` argument to the stack.
3. next step is to put return value in `eax` register from `main` function(return 0)
4. two next opcodes are function epilogue - you are cleaning up used stack and restore previous frame pointer register.
5. and the last one instruction is simple return.

Comment: Would probably be good to point out why rbp-8 is `&x`: because it's on the stack.  I'm not sure which part the OP doesn't understand, whether it's what [LEA does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658294/whats-the-purpose-of-the-lea-instruction), or why it's used *that way*.