# Trouble with array and colored text

Tags: assembly, emu8086

I want to color some letters using this proc:

```
markText proc
    mov ax,data
    mov ds,ax
    mov es,ax

    mov cx, M
    mov dx, 1
    push dx 
    mov Counter, 0
    mov si, 0
colorText:
    mov  ah,13h ;SERVICE TO DISPLAY STRING WITH COLOR. 
    push ax
    mov al,[CharMas+si]
    cbw
    mov bp, ax;STRING TO DISPLAY.
    inc si
    pop ax
    mov  bh,0 ;PAGE (ALWAYS ZERO).
    mov  bl,Color
    mov L, cx
    xor cx, cx
    mov  cx,1 ;STRING LENGTH.
    mov  dl,0 ;X (SCREEN COORDINATE). 
    mov  dh,b.ColorRepeat ;Y (SCREEN COORDINATE). 
    int  10h ;BIOS SCREEN SERVICES.
    mov cx, L 

    inc ColorRepeat
    loop ColorText

    mov AX,4C00h
    int 21h

markText endp
```

In my array (CharMas) I have got smth like: 'a','b','c'. But there is just a black blank instead of colored letters. What is wrong with my code?

P.S. it works perfect if I change index of arr to 0 or 1, e.g:

```
mov bp, offset CharMas[0]
```

Comment: in dseg:
CharMas DB 50 dup(13)
after filling:
'r', 'g', 'u', 'h', 'u', '
', '
', '
', '
', '
'

Comment: Try include in your question the declaration of `CharMas` and `b` and any other thing useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Write Character String" BIOS function requires a pointer to the output string in ES:BP. This is exactly what your "good" code does:

```
mov bp, offset CharMas[0]
```

However, your "bad" code

```
mov al,[CharMas+si]
cbw
mov bp, ax
```

loads 1 byte from the string into `bp`. What you need to do it put the *pointer* to that byte into `bp`. You can do it like this:

```
mov bp, offset CharMas[0]; now bp is a pointer to the string
add bp, si; now bp is a pointer to a specific byte in the  string
```

Or actually you can use just one instruction to do this:

```
lea bp, CharMas[si]; now bp is a pointer to a specific byte in the  string
```

Here `lea` is the [load effective address](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1658294/509868) instruction.

Comment: This BIOS video function 13h *also* requires that `AL` be set to specify a sub-function. See [the documentation](http://webpages.charter.net/danrollins/techhelp/0131.HTM).

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> mov  ah,13h ;SERVICE TO DISPLAY STRING WITH COLOR.
> ```

You've chosen one of the more difficult BIOS functions to output your colored characters. Moreover you're not using the parameters correctly!

Luckily there's a very much more user friendly function that you can use.

```
 mov si, OFFSET CharMas
 mov cx, 1
 mov bh, 0
 mov bl, color
Again:
 mov ah, 09h
 lodsb               ;Get next character from array
 int 10h             ;Outputs the colored character
 mov ax, 0E0Ah       ;0Ah=Linefeed
 int 10h             ;Advances the cursor to the next line
 cmp byte ptr [si], 0
 jne Again

CharMas  db  'a','b','c',0
```

Comment: Another great solution, I'll keep it in mind for future. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really sure I agree that this is any more user-friendly. You still have to get the parameters right, but your solution requires a lot more code, not to mention the fact it is slower. All you really need to do is follow the documentation, no matter which function you're going to use.

Comment: @CodyGray All tests I conducted in preparation for [today's Q/A about displaying characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747002/displaying-characters-with-dos-or-bios/44747003#44747003) show that the code presented by Fifoernik is neither longer nor slower. Don't forget that the OP is (ab)using the BIOS *WriteString* function 13h to output just **a single character**, thereby suffering a big BIOS overhead.

Comment: Well, I believe that for a single character. But I was speaking more generally. Did your tests actually show that this loop (and with `LODSB` of all things) was equally as fast for printing a moderate-length string as the BIOS function designed to do that? I guess that's possible, if you have a particularly inefficient BIOS implementation… By the way, @Sep, thanks for putting together that Q&A. Looks like an *excellent* canonical dupe target for all of the "debug my text output" questions we get!

Comment: @CodyGray If the BIOS *WriteString* function is used to output an entire string with just the one call, it can't be beaten provided the string involved reaches a certain length. The tipping point I found is at 4 characters.